# Longest code to add two numbers

Tags: number, code-bowling

**Task:**

I know we can all add two numbers the short way, using `+`. Your task is to create the longest code you can to add two input numbers.

**Rules:**

- All of the code must be on topic (don't fill it with non-addition code to add length)
- The count is in characters, but do not count tabs, spaces, or newlines.
- Do not use extraneously long variable names
- This is [code-bowling](/questions/tagged/code-bowling), so the longest answer wins!

Comment: What is the range of the input numbers (maximum and minimum)? Is the program expected to work with integers or floats? Is it expected to add negative numbers? Is there any specific input format? (For example, number system? i.e. decimal/binary etc)

Comment: Does `a + b - b + b...` count? It would be infinite

Comment: The longest algorithm to add two numbers is (quite trivially) provably infinite.  For this problem, the winner should be the most creative and circuitous (which is a challenge) rather than simply the longest (which is not).

Comment: Should we not count **any** spaces and newlines, or only those not required for the program for function? I'd say the latter would be saner.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc If you make that infinite, I think that equates to `a + b/2`, not `a + b` (it's similar to [Grandi's series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandi's_series)).

Comment: @TimS. Do it with an even number of b, not arbitrary number

Comment: @TimS. It is a divergent series, it ***does NOT equate*** to anything if you actually make that an infinite sum.

Comment: Do you want 100% code coverage?

Comment: @user80551 there are several ways to define infinite sums. Many of them actually manage to assign a sum to the infinite series `1-1+1-1+1...` and that sum is `1/2`

Comment: To make this more interesting, You should make it a rule that the length of the code are counted after compressed using, say Gzip our something like that.

Comment: @TheDoctor Did Mukul Kumar win this challenge? I'm new to this part of SE and wanted some clarification for Comintern's response and whether or not he failed to follow the rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## C++ MORE THAN 3x10^+618  (WITHOUT WHITE-SPACES,tabs or newlines)

This code took more maths than logic! in counting number of bytes

**SHORT CODE**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
long double sumofxandy(long double,long double);
int main()
{
    long double x,y;
    cin>>x>>y;
    sumofxandy(x,y);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
long double sumofxandy(long double x,long double y)
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
    if(x==0)if(y==-1)return -1;
    if(x==0)if(y==0)return 0;
    if(x==0)if(y==1)return 1;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    if(x==1)if(y==0)return 1;
    if(x==1)if(y==1)return 2;
    ...so....on.
}
```

#### OUTPUT

Really ? seriously! you want to see output? this code would take weeks to write and months to compile!

Comment: Steal.. err I mean acquire quantum computer

Comment: @RichardA BTW the strike tag is '<strike>' and not <s>

Comment: Doesn't work in comments though.

Comment: <strike>Let me try</strike> yes you are right

Comment: I believe it's `<del>`: <del>test</del>
Nevermind

Comment: <b>bold bold</b> @TheDoctor I think no tags work in comments!

Comment: @MukulKumar except `th`is `one` r`ight`?

Comment: @TheDoctor Which one is it? BTW why I am not worthy of up-votes?

Comment: @MukulKumar there is a lot of up vote inequality in this question

Comment: @TheDoctor the new (1 day - 2 months old) users never look down they gape at 1st answer give'em up-votes and off to other question

Comment: How is this supposed to be "MORE THAN 3x10^+618"? A long double is most likely 80 bits, resulting in less than 2^160 lines of giant if chain. Moreover, it's just using the same idea as Comintern's answer with a different data type.

Comment: There's an error in your code. What if `x` or `y` isn't an integer?

Comment: A pity that this answer is accepted just due to using long, while the idea is already present in the top-voted Comintern's answer below.

Answer (score 148):

### **C - 2,739,341,494,945,868,415,002 (Not including whitespace)**

Brute force for the win. Only handles integers, and preserves overflow behavior. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
int addnumbers(int x, int y)
{
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483648) return 0;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483647) return 1;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483646) return 2;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483645) return 3;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483644) return 4;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483643) return 5;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483642) return 6;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483641) return 7;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483640) return 8;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483639) return 9;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483638) return 10;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483637) return 11;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483636) return 12;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483635) return 13;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483634) return 14;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483633) return 15;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483632) return 16;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483631) return 17;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483630) return 18;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483629) return 19;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483628) return 20;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483627) return 21;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483626) return 22;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483625) return 23;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483624) return 24;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483623) return 25;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483622) return 26;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483621) return 27;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483620) return 28;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483619) return 29;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483618) return 30;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483617) return 31;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483616) return 32;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483615) return 33;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483614) return 34;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483613) return 35;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483612) return 36;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483611) return 37;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483610) return 38;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483609) return 39;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483608) return 40;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483607) return 41;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483606) return 42;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483605) return 43;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483604) return 44;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483603) return 45;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483602) return 46;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483601) return 47;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483600) return 48;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483599) return 49;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483598) return 50;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483597) return 51;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483596) return 52;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483595) return 53;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483594) return 54;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483593) return 55;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483592) return 56;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483591) return 57;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483590) return 58;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483589) return 59;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483588) return 60;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483587) return 61;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483586) return 62;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483585) return 63;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483584) return 64;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483583) return 65;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483582) return 66;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483581) return 67;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483580) return 68;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483579) return 69;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483578) return 70;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483577) return 71;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483576) return 72;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483575) return 73;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483574) return 74;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483573) return 75;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483572) return 76;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483571) return 77;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483570) return 78;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483569) return 79;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483568) return 80;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483567) return 81;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483566) return 82;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483565) return 83;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483564) return 84;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483563) return 85;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483562) return 86;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483561) return 87;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483560) return 88;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483559) return 89;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483558) return 90;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483557) return 91;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483556) return 92;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483555) return 93;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483554) return 94;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483553) return 95;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483552) return 96;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483551) return 97;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483550) return 98;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483549) return 99;
    if (x == -2147483648 && y == -2147483548) return 100;
    //etc...
}
```

This is obviously way to big to upload either here or on Pastebin, so here's a program that will generate the source code for the function (direct the output to a file - assuming you have the drive space):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x, y;
   printf("int addnumbers(int x, int y)\n{\n");
   for (x=-2147483648;x<2147483648;x++) 
   {
      for (y=-2147483648;y<2147483648;y++) 
      {
         printf("\tif (x == %d && y == %d) return %d;\n", x, y, x+y);
      }
   }
   printf("}\n");
}
```

I shudder at how long the function for long longs would be...

**EDIT:** Recalculated the score (should be correct) to give exact count. I prefer to think that I golfed it by 10²² characters when I removed the whitespace.

Comment: You had me at *snippet of the code*.

Comment: Whenever someone describes test-driven development as "do the minimum thing to make the new test pass", this type of code always pops into mind...

Comment: @Izkata - Yep, and it's all fun and games until the tester says "Great! We passed the addition tests.  Now for the subtraction tests...".

Comment: You know you could make this longer if you use `else if`.

Comment: You could also define separate named constants for each of the integers (`LEFT_SIDE_NEG_2147483648 = -2147483648`)... it's good practice to use descriptive names instead of hard-coded values, you know.

Comment: ... and wrap `return X;` with brackets: `{ return X; }` or use longer variable names instead of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Did they pay you per line of code?

Comment: Did they pay you per character?  You reduced your pay _significantly_ by using short-circuiting.

Comment: @JasonC OK, the named constant idea made me laugh. Even more "descriptive" would be `#define LEFT_SIDE_NEG_TWO_ONE_FOUR_SEVEN_FOUR_EIGHT_THREE_SIX_FOUR_EIGHT = -2147483648`  The only problem with adding more characters is that I'd have to figure out the count again...

Comment: You should have used int64_t and input by string using atol() in each statement.

Comment: @Radiodef, I love your suggestion because it not only would make the code long but also "better" written.  Of course, he could go full retard and do switch statements in switch statements

Comment: Objection, on the grounds that you clearly haven't tested the code. (And no, I'm not about to test this for you).

Comment: @nneonneo Umm.... it's still compiling?  :-)

Comment: Has anybody noticed that the program to add `ints` has a size not representable with `ints`

Comment: You could add a few billion characters by using octal (2147483648 => 020000000000) and hex (0 => 0x0) as (in-)apprioriate.

Comment: But this does not conform to the rules of the question. The question doesn't say integers only. This code should be much longer!

Comment: Did anyone benchmark this compared to operator+?  I'm incredibly curious.

Comment: I can try as soon as my 3 Zettabyte harddisk arrives. Don't hold your breath, though...

Comment: For `long long` there would be `3.4028237e+38` if-statements, or (hopefully I shifted the dot correctly) `340282370000000000000000000000000000000`, assuming an average of 50 bytes per if-statement, this would be `1.5845633e+31` GiB, or `15845633000000000000000000000000` GiB, which is `140737490000000000` Yobibyte, I think.

Comment: I thought the behaviour for overflow on signed integers was *undefined*. How exactly is it 'preserved' (i.e: what behaviour does it actually exhibit on overflow?)

Comment: @Kninnug - If you generate the code with the same compiler, it will give the same undefined result as the original additions would have.

Answer (score 21):

## C++, 3573

3573, then it was getting boring, but I can continue adding more layer of abstraction.

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Number
{
public:
   typedef int Representation;
   class InvalidNumber
   {
   };

   Number();
   Number( const InvalidNumber& invalid );
   explicit Number( const Representation& v );
   friend Number operator + ( const Number& rop, const Number& lop );

   bool operator == ( const Number& v );
   bool operator != ( const Number& v );
   bool operator == ( const Representation& v );
   bool operator != ( const Representation& v );

   bool IsValid() const;
   Representation GetRepresentation() const;
private:
   Representation mValue;
   bool mValid;
};

Number::Number()
   : mValue { 0 },
     mValid { false }
{
}

Number::Number( const Number::InvalidNumber& invalid )
   : mValue { 0 },
     mValid { false }
{
}

Number::Number( const Representation& v )
   : mValue { v },
     mValid { true }
{
}

bool Number::IsValid() const
{
   return mValid;
}

Number::Representation Number::GetRepresentation() const
{
   return mValue;
}

bool Number::operator == ( const Number& v )
{
   return ( v.mValid == mValid ) && ( v.mValue == mValue );
}

bool Number::operator != ( const Number& v )
{
   return ( v.mValid != mValid ) || ( v.mValue != mValue );
}

bool Number::operator == ( const Number::Representation& v )
{
   return ( mValid ) && ( v == mValue );
}

bool Number::operator != ( const Number::Representation& v )
{
   return ( !mValid ) || ( v != mValue );
}

Number operator + ( const Number& rop, const Number& lop )
{
   if( rop.mValid && lop.mValid )
   {
      return Number { rop.mValue + lop.mValue };
   }
   else
   {
      return Number { Number::InvalidNumber() };
   }
}

Number NumberParser( const char* numberString )
{
   const char* p = numberString;
   while( *p != '\0' )
   {
      if( !isdigit( *p ) )
      {
         return Number { Number::InvalidNumber() };
      }
      ++p;
   }
   Number::Representation value = atoi( numberString );
   return Number { value };
}

std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& os, const Number& num )
{
   if( num.IsValid() )
   {
      os << num.GetRepresentation();
   }
   else
   {
      os << "Invalid number";
   }
   return os;
}

class SimpleOperation
{
public:
   typedef Number Result_t;
   typedef Number Parameter_t;
   virtual ~SimpleOperation();
   virtual Result_t operator()( const Parameter_t&, const Parameter_t& ) = 0;
};

SimpleOperation::~SimpleOperation()
{

}

class AssociativeOperation : public SimpleOperation
{
};

class SimpleSum : public AssociativeOperation
{
public:
   virtual Result_t operator()( const Parameter_t&, const Parameter_t& );
};

SimpleSum::Result_t SimpleSum::operator()( const Parameter_t& a, const Parameter_t& b )
{
   Result_t res = a + b;
   return res;
}

class PackOperation
{
public:
   AssociativeOperation::Result_t operator()( const std::vector<AssociativeOperation::Parameter_t>& );
   virtual AssociativeOperation& getOperation() = 0;
};

AssociativeOperation::Result_t PackOperation::operator()( const std::vector<AssociativeOperation::Parameter_t>& parameters )
{
   AssociativeOperation& operation = getOperation();
   AssociativeOperation::Result_t tempResult = AssociativeOperation::Result_t { 0 };

   for( auto param : parameters )
   {
      tempResult = operation( tempResult, param );
   }
   return tempResult;
}

class PackSum : public PackOperation
{
public:
   virtual AssociativeOperation& getOperation();
private:
   SimpleSum mSum;
};

AssociativeOperation& PackSum::getOperation()
{
   return mSum;
}

void print_usage()
{
   std::cout << "Sum operator1 operator2\n";
   std::cout << "print the sum of the operator \n";
}

void print_parsingError( int argIndex )
{
   std::cout << "Error while parsing argument " << argIndex << "\n";
   std::cout << "Aborting...\n";
}

void print_result( Number res )
{
   std::cout << res << "\n";
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   if( argc < 3 )
   {
      print_usage();
      return 1;
   }
   std::vector<Number> addends;
   int opIdx = 1;
   while( opIdx < argc )
   {
      Number n = NumberParser( argv[opIdx] );
      if( n == Number::InvalidNumber() )
      {
         print_parsingError( opIdx );
         return 1;
      }
      addends.push_back( n );
      opIdx++;
   }
   PackOperation* op = new PackSum();
   Number result = ( *op )( addends );
   delete op;
   print_result( result );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Scary thing is this resembles code I've seen in my company for such mundane tasks =d.

Answer (score 12):

## Ruby, 29048 (can be as high as necessary, but I had to get it under the character limit for posts)

```
require 'zlib'

# gzip deflated data
data = "x\x9C\x01\xA3'\\\xD8x\x9C\x01\x98'g\xD8x\x9C\x01\x8D'r\xD8x\x9C\x01\x82'}\xD8x\x9C\x01w'\x88\xD8x\x9C\x01l'\x93\xD8x\x9C\x01a'\x9E\xD8x\x9C\x01V'\xA9\xD8x\x9C\x01K'\xB4\xD8x\x9C\x01@'\xBF\xD8x\x9C\x015'\xCA\xD8x\x9C\x01*'\xD5\xD8x\x9C\x01\x1F'\xE0\xD8x\x9C\x01\x14'\xEB\xD8x\x9C\x01\t'\xF6\xD8x\x9C\x15\xD0S@%\x8A\x02@\xD1\\\x93m\xE3d\xDB\xB6m\xDB\xB6\xED\x9Al\xDB\x93m\xDB\xB6m\xFB\xBD\xFB\xB5\xBE\xF7\xF6\xC8\x06~\x05@\xAD{d\x03_\x01P\xFEc\x1F\x80\xFF\x1F+\x00\xCA\xFF\x98\x04\xB0\xFCG\x1F\x80\xFF?\x9A\x01R\xFFQ\tP\xFD\x8F<\x80\xC1\x7F$\x03\xAC\xFF#\x12\xE0\xF6\x1F~\x80\xC0\xFFp\x06\xC4\xFC\x87\x05 \xED?t\x01\x85\xFF\xA1\x04\xA8\xF9?h+\xC6\xC2dQ \x02\xF36r\xE96\x9B-\xB6\x9B+&\x9B-\xD7I\xB6\x9B\xE91I\x9C\xEB\xB5\xAF7e\xCF(//S\xE0h\x85g\xBBwS\xE0\xA6e\xE9\x1F\b\xD8Q)\xBF\x84\xC5k\x9F\b.Q\xD1\xBF\x01%\x1E?\xF1\xF6Ns\xD3\xBF\x8F\x02qw\x04\xE6G\xBD\xBF\xA0\x12r\x0F\x04\xFE\xE3\xE7\xBF\xC6\xD9\xD9\x97\xFC^c\xA2\xBFE\t:\xFB\xFC\x13\xE3\xCD\xBF$\xE1[W\xFC\xC8\xE3x\xBF\b#\xE5\x15\x88~4\x98cA\xEF+36Y\xDFj\x9B)\xEF3%\x10\xDD\xE7b\xBBa\x9F.Y\xDF\x86\xB7\xD3\xE4\xAD\xFDaH\x14\x1F\xF9\xD7\xBF\x8E\x02\xF6_\x8Ci\xBD\xDC\xD7\xE2\xF9\x1F?3\xF9H\xFE\xD0\x7F\xD5\xEC\xDE\x7Fh9\xB8\x10\xE7\xCAI_\x1F\xB3|\x9E\xF4\x81*\x91wN\xED3\xE7\xCB\x80\f\x8Fs\xEBXun\x8E_\xF3\xEC\xA0\xC7\xEB\xBC\x1CN\xF7\b\xF0\x1E\xA2f\x81j,qP\x9EFx\x0FoN\xCFQ\xC2\xB98\xB4\xA0a\x95\v#\xC8\xDB\xE3\xC9;\xDF\tL\xCCK\xC9rOKl\x8E\xBDs\xF8\xB6\x18\xA0\xADn\x9E\xE9\xAE\xFE\xF5\xB4;\xEA\xBF\x87\xB2\xF4\xD6=\xDC\xDEl\xBA\x10\x8B\xED\x10\xF8\\7\xDE\x9A\x90p\xE5\xD1\xF3/\xCF\xAD\x96\x13\xC9\x15\xCB\xC3\x84U\xCB#\x19\xE2\x0E\xDB\x83wt\xB8\xFF\x99[c\xDD%(y\xCB\xDB#\xAC\x956\xE1l\xE6\xCF\xDB\xFF\xF4\xF1\x8A\xC8\x03\xCA\\e\x91L\xCD\a@\x87u\xAD\x1EZZ\xB2\xFEB\x999\x97l8\xEB\xC4q.\xF3\xC5\x19\x1Fk\xD6\x95\xC17:\xEAI \x93?\x91(\xEDG\x0E^\x0EW\xA4\xF0\xB4\xFD\x9D\xAC\x8B\x1A\x9Fqw\x8B)J\xF2\xEB0\xE1\x01\xD0\xC4\x04\x13@/M\xEB\x13*$w?\x95fmS\xBF]>\xB7\xD9\xA4\xF8[\x1E?\xF0\xE7m|\x89\x1C\xD0-\xE7\xF7h\xDF\xC3\xC0\xF0\xC4\x12\x06\xF9\xF0\xCD\xDD\xE9\xFB\x94\x1A\x98:\x98\xD6\xAF\xC6YH\x1A2\xF0\xF2\xF9\r\xFE\x94O\xEEtm\x8F\xB7\x92xL\x88\xEA\xF9\x1CM\xA5\x89\x8D\xC4<9\xA1\x95\tJ\xE4\xDA\xF2U\xE3\x84uO\xD3\x84\xC6CN\x87\xFC{a\x99\xF9\x9D|g\xD31\xD8+*\x16\xF2YD!F\xEC\x8D[\xFA\xD3\xBE.Rs\xAD\xBC\x05\x81T\x11\x1FLJn]H\ev\xFAvB?\x99S7\x9Ad8X\xC0s\x93\xF6\x12\xB4\x8C\\\xEE)\x90\"Y`\xE5\xC7\xE6\xA4\xF1\xC1\xB0\xFE\x128V\x1A6\xE9\\\xDF\xBFVM\xAEa(\x8E\xEC .\xC4^)$B~^\xAD\x9A2\x8E\x84\x05J\x04\xCF\xA8\xD2\x82\xB4-\x06RvfU? \x02j\xF0\xDE\e\xCC\xD3\x1FW\xAA\xF2\xD6\xCD\xB21a\x8D\xCE\xC7\xAC\xC6eH\xA2\xF6E\x97\xE9\x1D\x1F\x1A2\x85\xFF\xC7\xD5'\xA2\xDD\xCE\xEBk\x11l\x93\xB1\a)/\xA1i\xBF\x9E\xE3\x82m\xF8|\x9E\x13Y#\xE5\x9C\xED0p\f\xC3\x97_\xBEB\xFE\xB0\xE4\xF0\xC4\xF5bu\x84n\x16\xF2\x12\xBE\xFE\x05<\xDD\xB5\x8E\xDE\xCAq\e\xB6\x17\xDE$\x1F\xD4V8Le\xDC\xDB\xC2\xAB\xF1\x03\xCE\xEF\xA22\xDD\xE3cxt\xB8\xD9\x97*d{\x8F\xC7\xF0\x9F\xF5\xB7L\x8D\xED\t V\x1D\b\xABz\xF2\x82\xFB\xFE\xE0~/z\x7F\xCA\xD2\xF2\x1F\x01\xEDD\x9CM\xDE4t\xFE|\xAF\xE3\xC8\x90E\xB8\\\xAC\xFDs\xFB\xDF:\xF0h\xE5K\x18\xD3\x14\x80\xDC\xB8we\xA2!\x83\r\xF71\x9C\x82\xA9K\x84\xB0\x98b\x13\x85\xAF\xD4\x10\xF0\xC0\x05\x94\t\xA1j\xF4v\xA7\x7F\xD8\x89\x18\aj\xAD<Ymvv\xC7\xA9L\xC7\xE2\x93\xFE}F&\n\xDD\bE\x9B\xDC^jW/g\xDA\xF5\xA6\x87\v\xE3\e`d\xC7\x9F\xF1\v\xCA\x9As\xA0\xB3\r\xDCt\xC1\x9AL\xEDU\xCF\x03\xAD\x181\x18|?\x16\xF2\xB7\xCD\xC1x=B\xB4'\xD0E\xE8\x00\xDA\xC7F\x14\xD1H\x13%\xC18\x16\x82\xF8I\x92\xE5\xE9\aw\xFD\x93$\xB1\xB5\x98d\xD4\xBF\x9A<\x1F\xC9\x0F\xFD\xAB\x82\xF5\x0E\x92i&\bQ\xAA\x9Eb\xEDg\vF6\xC6\xC0i\xDBF\xE0\x06[U\xA8\x82\xA8\x17\xF8\xDA\xA0\xB9\xED}J\xF0>\x91\xEB\x0F\x8F\xC3\x96\xA9\xF0\x02\x9C\xA1\x1F]\xFC\xE2X\x11)\xDF\xC5F\xC1*\xD6Y\xEB\x05F\xD7VI\xCF\x1D\xBD\x1E\x13\x8EN~t\xD8(\x81\xC2\xCC\xE97\xC3\x91\xAC\x10\x18\r\xA8\x9D\xC9S\xD4\x81\"d\x81\xF9c\x8A\xF3\xDAe\xE6~\xEFan\x03\xBEQ\xB2\xFD\x9A\xFC\x13\xDCkz\xB8\xBDa\xAD\x15\xAC9\x9C>\xDC\x00\xD1\xE6\xAB\xC7\xC4\x0F\x1A\x9B\x9E:\xC3\xE2\x14\xF7\xC8hz\xC0\x1CT\x06\xC3=\xCD}j\xE7\xDD\x90\xF2\xCD!\x9E\x95\x8A6\x01\xE2\xBAfw<\xD3I\x88\x80\x80\xD8\xA8\xD3\x96\x91o\nFY\xDB\eg\x84\xB5\x0E\xEE\x04\b-\xA6\e\x05\xE5\xF1\x99\x92w\x1A\\|\xE8\xE8K\xD1\xCD\x99\xC69\xDC\x87\x16\xC4\x12uJ\x87b\x80\xDF&}\xF3\xEF\x83\xBA\x8F\x95\x9A\xCDD\x01\xA7\xC9\xB3u\xE5$\f\x05\xBD\x94\xD3\x90\x0FX\xDC\xED\xB6\x8A*9\xB7\xCE?\x0E\xDBl\xC6J\xFC\xBD-\rna\x94\x0E\x18*U\xF5\xC9\a\x197\x9A\xD9\xB9Q+,'\xDC\x1A\xBD\x83\x9DV\t\x7Fak\xBE~'\xBDb\xDAL*\x98\xF6\xB6Xbpvx\xD8\xCC\x12\xB6\xFB\xBDG\x18\xB5qE:q\xD8\xB4\xE0\x04\xBB\xAB\"\x1AF\xAB;\xC7_\xE5\x8Cg\xAFQ3\xACN\x91\f<\xAF\xE9Zh\"7\xA3N[Q93\xBA\xEFp\xDDQ@\xBC|\xF9/\xD6\x949\xD9\xCA,\xB5\xD9s\xCC\x03b@\xB7\xEE\xD8HR\x1A#%\"~\x93\x95\x7F\x90~ZR\x8Fsm\xC0\x9C\xCD%J\x00\x90\x84\x992\xE8\x87\xC9\xE2\xDCj\x1DF\x03\xC5\x19\x85\x15\xBE\xF2\xA4\xF1\xB1j\xAA\x93\xA8\xA9\x82\xD1|\xC5\xC3\xD2\xF9\xAC\x16\b\xAD\xABE|\xE7\xF9`\xE7A2;\xA8\x98\xF5:\xD0\x8C\x94\xDF\xD8\x04\xFC\a\xE3vU\xA2L\x8AnE\x8A\x12S\av\xE9\xAD\x9B\x92\xEA\xD2\xD4s\x0E\x14 \xE3\x89m'\x8EY\x95,9\xC2\xC8\xDEM\xCE\xEC_\xD3\x1Eec\xE4\x8C\xAB&\xD4\xC0\x1C\xB0\x87\x10\xE3km\xCF\x96\xBB,\n\x9B\xE8g,\xDE\x06\x03\xD4\x1FGG\x91~\x10Fw\xC1\xD1\x8A\xC7>2\xE6\xD4F\a\xC8\xDD8\xCA+\xEE\xE6s\xB6h\x87\x12\xBFL\xEE\xE8T\x96\xCD\xC4X\xB1VK\xCF&\xCE\x9C\x05Q\xD4\xC1r\xFE\x0F\xE8L\xD1\xD9\xDCb\x8F\xAA3\xE5\xBC\xD5\x8B\xBB\x8A\"Q\r\xC5\x84{\xCB|\xDB\xAC\x90\x1Ei\xD6\xE0GIc_\xDE(\xF9d\xFA\xA0\x9C.\xF7\x8Cc\n\xA4\xB9\a\xD7\xB1\xA10\xA5i\xEBW\x8B\xF5VV~\a\xEE_\x9F\x85\x18\xD3 \xC8\x14\x10\xE4\xB4\vDf\x0E&\x96\xAE\x180\xCFX\x01\xCB\x80&\x9E\xDC\xF4\xB9\rx\xB2\\i\xAA\xE5^\x9C\x15\x8FY\x10\x03H\xEB\xBC,c\xA3k\x84>\x88|\xA3K\xCFD\xE5\x92\x8Ev\x80\xE3\xED\xB2I3\x0EH-Kh%3;\xFD\x8BfS\xE0\x82z\xBF\x1E\x8A(W\xF8P\xA0\xBF\x1F$\xBA3s\f\x92\xD5w\xA4m\x1D\x0Fa\x10\x10\xF74\x02<\t\xB4$k\x15%\xD2m\x85\xB8n\t]dv\xE1\r\x93!k\x8C\xC4\xC1\xE776>a8\xAC-\x1A\x03\xC6Uj~\x8A\x91F\x0E\xEDM\xEF\x9B\xD2\xDBY\xAE\xF8K\xB7n\xA4\xD4\xA0i\xFAa\xF7\xD6\xDFn\x13s\x8E\x98`\xE3Ku`\xE9\xDD\xDB;\x8A\xDE\x0E\x87\xA7\xA4\xF4c:\xE2\xB9\xBBf*\xEE\x03\x80E\x1F\xD7\x92\xE9\xB3\x14\x18\x1D\xE3\xBF\xF0`\xE3\"\xFE\xC4d\x82eqq\xE7\x83\xB2\xFE\x8BH\x01\x8Fe\x850>V\x8A\xE2\xD50 \xCF\xAE5]\x9F\xDFdm\xF6\x9Dr\x86\xF7\xF7#z)\x87\xCE\xA1\x86\xB9\xF7\xF6XO\xC5\xD7P\x0Fx5\xA8\xD4Buj\xDD\xD7\x83\b\xE3\xBF\xEA~\xB6\xA5\xBC>\x8A\x99Gp\x87\n\xA6s\x9A\x11\xC0\xE1VD\xE0\xB4\xF3\x9A\xE9\xA5\x89\xB6\xF7oQ\xD7\xEF<\x7FB\xC9/p2\xEE\xD4\xDD\xE5;\xAAc\x1F\xECWP\xB0/\xAE:\xEE1\xF8\x9D\xEF\x94\xD1\x87i\x82it\x0E\x86\xEAA\x9C\x1A\xC7*\xFA\xAA\x05\xC8l\xCD\xD3\x84W\xB0\\\x9F\xA9\xDD\xFF\xF2`8\xDF_,\xB8\xA7q\xE07=V %\xE1\x9DX\x80\e\x15k\xCDe\x18k \xAAz\xCCb\xD3\xDD[\xAC,\xFE\xCB\x1D\xBC\xA6\xD8\xED\x7F\xC9f-\x1C\x8B\xF6\xDF\xCA\x05\xBE\xEC\x15q\xB7[=\r,R\xC5|\xAFX\xAAR\xCBd~\x8D\x1Fs\xD8Ow\xE4\x1F\x18\xF4A$\xF7k\x11\xB0\x10E\xB0>\x12\xE5\x99\x88\xF7n'\xAAPg\x1A\xD0\xC7\x1E!\xBF\x85\xBF\xF7aL\x9E\xF0\xA7\x9D\x91c\xAC-%s\xFFT\xC1\f\x84X\x1D\x06\xA8\x13\xF2T\xF0V*\x8Ay4\x84\xE8Z\x83Q\x9A\xA0D\xC1\x1D$=0\xEB?\xB4\x94\x91K\xBF\xB6\x8C\x1C\x82\xB2\xC5\xB3\x9D\xE3]\x00aU\xB4\x8F\xCB\eo\x8F\x8E\xF5\xB7.h\f+9\e\x8F5\xD8s<\x11O\xEC\x84\x02\a\x1A\xA1\xEFy\xE6\xA2d/\x03\xB7\x87ey:\x93\xC6eL0-\xA69%~\xE6C\xB7\x8A!i\xD5>b\xA2\x91\x19\xF2\xFB\xB4b\xEF\xA2E \x8Amm\xAE\x97\xDC\x98\xFAH%h\xBE\xC7\xDAk\x9E\t\x7F\xE2\xE5\xEF8\x8A\xE3\xF0\x99\x94\xA8#K\xFB\xF5s|\x13\xF6$\x9A\xDFg@\x8D\xEF.]\xDB\xFBw\xA2\xCB\n6r\x9Ex\x9A\xCC\x88\x80\xF2\xF2\xC5x)q&\xFD\xFD]\x11h\xD9M\x924\xAB\x83\xDE\xAE\xB8\x87\xDF\x93\xFF\xFB[\x8F\xBF\xCAM{#\x11I\x849\xA7\xC1\xE9-\xFD\xFA\x11\v\xE7\x13\xE0\xF8\x02\xDD%\xF6\xBD\x06\x18\x8A\xA7n\xA8rh\xD5\xFA}\x1E\xC1Gee\rrx\xC3\xA8\x80~y\xED@\x8B\x99\x91\x81\x93y\xD3\xF0\v5E\x12\xFD\x19{\xF0B\x8Fr\x12J-\x9A|x\xEF\xBD\xA8\x96\xA3_\xA8\x96\xF3-\xEB\\/\xF6\x03\xEFGf\xA6\xB1)\xF2?ex\f\r\xD7\x16\x16y\x7F\xD3\xD6j\x81\x9C\xFE\x90\xB7\xD8\xE6\x83\x02NG\xE8p\xEC,r{\v=\x03\xE0\xC9\xD6\x8A\xF1\xCD}\xBFjTf$Ezw|\xBD\x92\x03A`\vn\xB4\xE8\x86\v\x04\xDB\xCA\xEB \x8F\xDC\xFFx%|\xE5\xE7F\xD1K\xCE\x9F\x86\xD8\xA5o\xDB$\xDD\x86\x8E\xE6\xF88t\xFB\xF9\xFC#\x19\xDBtA\x1Een}\x90\xEEZndo\x99D!W\x8E\xF6\xFB\x03w8\x0E\xC6\xB2\x96f\xF2\x9C\x12Y\xFA\x84G\x8A\xF8\x1A\xB0\xAE*$\x82{\xF3\xC3\xCEc\x87\x03\xFF\xEF\xC0s\xD0&8\xA5\xF7\xC5X\x11\x1C+\xF5X\xA9\x05\x04\xDE4\x1A\xD3\xB1\xCB\x9C\x8F\\\xB7\xE5\xE2\x83\xC9\xB1\xC8\x88b \x8E\xA3\xC1+Q<\x05=\xA6d\xE9%?\x18\xA5\a;\xF5\xD9\xF8`\xC2\xAA\xE7\x1DZ\xD2\xEE\xEEw\xEA3\xC9\x9D\xE4\xDB\xFF\xBBM\xEC\xFC\x1E\xCA\xDBf\xB1\xBEE\x82\xB8A\xAC\xE5\x9Ab\xFAU\xC7\xF1!\x16z\x03\x99`\xD8\xF1D\xF2\xD0\xE1\xD2\x85\"\xDC.\xFE\x98\n\xD2\x18\x06\x81!\xBB\xA8\x01F\x0F\x0F\xDF\"\n^\xD8R\xFF\xDF\xA5\x04'<y\x95m\x97\xDA\xB6\xD9\xD2\xF4\x976\xB2\xACw\x83[\x8B\x18\xDD\x99opw\x93T\xD2.\x91O\xA8\x91\x80\x86\xB7a\xB8\xEF\xFA\xA6\xCBIB\xFD\"\x1A}\bk\xD5\x98\xA4i\xFCj\xA40\xEB-#\xF1\x17\xDF\xD3(\xB5\x85K\xE3\xDD\x94\xD9\xAA\xDBo\x94\xF4\x04\xA1;\xAC\xB0\x186[},\x1Ee \xBB\xD6V\xC1\xC4J\xD3\x00\x9D\xEDD\xA6\xC9\x87\xFA.7eN\xD4:\x9B\x85\x989N\xC5\xEE\xE4\xE2\xB5\xCBE\xE8\xF8H<\xF23\xCA\xD4\xDEy|'\xCF\xE7G,\xB3\n\x18\xC8\x81G\xA0\xDBm\x1D\xA7Q\xC5\xCF\xB3\x03a\xB1\xEF\xBAuL&\enD\x89\f\x8E\xFB\xB9\xC73mT\f\xB3\xEFJ\xC6\xA0_k3\x84}\xD1%r\xAB\xB5\xBD\x05\x01K(\xAD\n\xE1\x1D\xA0\xF4R\fA{\xF5W\xF3%\xE9\xFA\xF0\xE4\x98\xAF\x05\\c\v\x98\xB7a\x8B\xD9\xD6\"\r\xC74p\x9D\x8C\xB0:\xFD\x8E\xBB]\xEB\xC7OR\xBF\t'|B\xC1\xFC`\x85\xAF\xE8y7\x11\x82p\xA4\xFDF\xA4\xFB'iD\x95p\x88\xC9\x94\xE1\xBB\xBD\x91\xA5\xF9\xAFTL\xB1\xD4C\x01\xF3\xC7\xFE\xD0\x8C \x82})\x1E\x7F\x99\xAF\xD4%a\x03\xC1\xFE\xB7#\x11\xDA\x9F\x82\x93\xB5nq\x11|\x03\x99\xC4\xD3\xA8\xBB\xC5&<z\xE4\xFAE6c:\x02\x13r\xF3#\xB9\xB5I\x9E\x05C<\x052\x92\x7F6\v\tIt\x0E\xAA\x1C\x1Cw\xB0C\x99[\xDD\xEB\xD0\x12\x84\xED\f\xA3\xD82\xAC,d'\xB5\x12g\xD74\xFC\xF3\xE2\x8AB\xB4{r\xB7\xFE\xDB:\xFC\b2\xAA\xD5\x06\xEFS\xBB,\x834\xE2\xB7D\xD4x\xB9!\e\xA1\x10\xE1#\xF3_\xA6\x9F[\xA5\xFE7g\x8A&_/`\xC4\xAD\x8FB\xE5\xFC.\x96\xB0\vn\xB6c\x17\xF1\x8F\x1E{r=\xABQ\xE0 \x1C\xC7\x1A\xFC\xE5w\xEEbl/lW\xBB\x9B\xE6\xA6\xAF\x01<%\xF0\x12\xAA*\xB3\xEC\xF8\x84=\x16\x1D\x91:\xE3ss\xCFg\x18n\v\xD7Q\x93.\xFA\x9B-U\x86K\x06xn\xF9\xB1\xE9\x8E\x7F\x03\xDB\x91\xF1\xE1\xEC\r[\xFD\xBF[\x1Ajkpc5\x1D\xCA\xCB\xC44_\x1F\xB4\xB3\x15\xC8\xC3\x8A\xD33O~K,$\x1C@\xB2s8\x81\xFC\xBC\x89,L\xD8\xA0\xC6\xBC\xB4\x88Y\xEDE\xF9~\xC805\nAc\xFE~\x11\xDF\xBA&\xA1591\xDC]\xD6\xE8\xA5D\xE1\xD0}>\xAA\x9A\xF8\x19\t\xCB\xD6s\xEA=\x99=\xDBac\x81R\xD9\xBBN\xB4S\x95\x1A\xF9\tpz\xFD\x8D\xFF\x90#|\xF5:\xE4#\xE8\x8F\xFA\xA7Y\xF6%\x82\r\x97X#wTS1b\xFE\xA2I\x1D}\x97\x88\xAC\xD6\x17\xB3\xA2\xB6~\xF0#X\xE1\xF6\xDA\xBC'G\xF1!\x8F*\xC3nb\xA5\x80\x9D\x81.\x14\xA0\xF3\xD8\x9E^$\x89\x7F\xB9\bU@,J$\x1A\xB3\xCB\xD4\xB3|\x82*^\xCAn\xF3\xF0**V\x17\f.\xF3\xAD\x91\x1Eh\xEA\x98\xB4\xC1h\xE0\xFD\b4\xE9\x8E\xB5v\x03\x9Er\x82A\x03\vA;\xC6B\xF1\xB3\xFD\x9A\x8C:\xC2!\xBC\xB1\xDC3Z\xEA\r\x9D\xCF\"\xBE\x92mK\x9F<\x9E\x06/\xD6\xF1\xEC\xC8\xD8\xFC\x9E9\xFE\\\x99z\xDF\x90,\xA9'\x9E\x9DS\xE96\xBC\x96as\xB3x\xC9S\xCC\x96\xEAqg\x02\xA5\xDE\x17=\x80\xBC'\xAD\xF0f=\x9C\x84g:\xAD]\xA4\xE0/\x9D\xF5\xA0\xBA\x1E\xBC\xA1\x86\x99\x98\xB3\xA5\xA4\xE5j'\xB7),b\xED\aR\x96%HM\x1E\xC9\x837\xB5w-\xD9(\x17\xF5\x9B\x9D\xBC\xCB\x89\x1D\x11\x16RO\xC7f\xB1z\x16K\xBA6\xE6\xAA\xF5\x9C\xD9\x1E\xDFz:oE(\xC9\xD2m\x19\xCA\x93\xAF\xD7k\xC4\xFAB\x11N\xFCw\fp\xD6\x8B\x04\\\xBC\x04\x04v\r\xE5\xC3\xA4\xC0\x0F5\xE7\xD1\xA2\xD7\xE4\xF9\\c\x1C,\x00\x054\xCD\x94;\xF6\xF5t1\x7F\x99qj\xCF\xD8\xDC\xB83\x9C1\xB0-\\\xDFA\xE9\xF2\x00%XQ\xD7\xA3Lb\aF\xEB\xD3\xF2\xF5\x93=\x1C\x19h\x90n\xFCB\xAF\x9B\xDC\xCDo\xC0W\xCD\x0E\xC8 qO\xBA\x97<\xEF)\x98\xEB[\xB4wD\xE9\xEEQ\rD3\x97\a\xC7\x912\xD1\xE6aq'\xEC\x1A\xE4\xBF\xC9\xE093\xCF\xECy!>\x14:_\xCA\xFF\xB8\xC1u\xBF\xE7?\x90O\xEFv\aa\x8Ex\x1A\xCC\xC0\xAAO:\x84\xFF2\xA6\xA4H\b\x06]\x93N\x88\xD3\xBFx\xD5U]\x92\xC4\xE1\xC1\xDB\xC1\xFCq8Se\xE2\x931\xCD\xB7\x8C\xCF\xD4\">\a\x8DS\e\tH\xC5\xEB\rM\xDD%\x0F\xA2\xF8\x9D\xA0\nZ\xDE(\x17\xB0\xCF\xCD\xB9\xE8\x9F\xFA\xFFh#x\xCB\x8C\x1F\xC7\x19~\xCD\xB8FI1\x96\xEA\t\x02\x14\xAB\x0FV#m\x16\x92;LU\x81\xBB6\x1C\x03\xE5\x90p\xA2\xEF\xC3\x8E\xFC\x0EF\xBD\xF7{({jC\xB7<R\xB1=%\xC7\xA2\xAD\x03\xE9\x91\xE9\xF7\xAAb\n~\x92\xF7\xE1\x16\xA1]\xF2\xFD8\xA2\\0\xC7\xEA\a\xE8\x14\x1E/\xF2=X\t\xE7\x99N\x93\xFC\xB1A\x89\xD2\xED2\xAA\xF9&\xF7\xB3\xD0ls\xFC\xD23\xCB\xA1\x84%HP\xF6G3\x8B\xA0\x82ga\x82I\xFB{\bqY\xC2\x97\xD5\xF8\xCF\xD7\x99\xA9\xA6\x01\xD0\x0FH\x99*Deu\xA9\xFD|\xF6BI\xC8\xD79}\xD1\x14>~>p\xBDh[T\x88\xFDk[N\xB3\x8E\xAA\xDA<\x89\x83\xDE\xF0\xEF\x0E\xB6\xCF\x9A]\xFA\xFA\x10\xFB\x96\xFE~\xEAs\xEE\xA7\xB7|\xCC\x9C9Yh\xFC-\xFC{6W\x8B\x95\xA5-\xDC\x1C\t\x1A\x9F\xF9\xF4m\x8B#\xFB;\xE0\xA6\xA8\xA7|<\xAF\v\xE3\xF6\x10r\xBD\xCFW12\xE5E\xD6\xC1\xC2.\xD6hr\xEC\x13\xD2\x84\n\xD8\x1Eyd\xE4_\xAB\xA9K\x8D<;\x11[\\,\x04\xE2\"\x92uQ\xE3\x83\xD1zt\x16+\xE4<Y[#\x06\x8C\xD95\xAD\xF5\xD1\x1C\xE9f\xEF\x06EAW\x90\xA2jK\xFA\x9BW\xE4/\xD9\x8F\x02L\xB8\x7Fx\xD7\xCC\xAB\xFA\xCC\xF7FY\xF4$\t\x1E\xCD\xED\xAF\x99\x92(\xAC\xC2\xAF\x17e\xAC\xB0iP\xFAp\xA0}5\f2\xAFp\xFAL\xE9\xC1\x8A\xC8\x10\xDC\xE2\xD3\xD5a\xCF#e\x19\xCE\xE9S\x8A\xD4.F0?\x04 \x9CQ$z\x8E\xDD\\Q\x95\x90\x01\xEF\xBC\xD7\x88\xF5\x97\xD8\xF7g\a\x1D\xAD\xF8Z\x85\xC2\xD5\xF6\xC9'\xA2n\xB7\xA3\x9A,\xCD=K\xE4\xF8\x8A\xDE\xBF\"\x99\xBD\\GN\x99M\x89\x93\x10\xFC\xBF\xCC\x03\xEES\xAE\b)\xBC\xDE\xDB\xA6\x01+%\xBCdW![-\x91\x85|\x89 \f\x1DI\x1Fpq\xD1\xFF\x1C\xD3*3\xB3\xF4\x03\xF2\xA4\\\a\x14\xCF\xF6u*\xB3D(zS \xE6\x17\xB6d4\x99\x88\xAE\xCD\x99\xBD\xF5.\xE9\xE7G6\"\f\x00x8`9\xD7\xD9\x19\xC1\xE9\xE3\xD2\xFF\x8F+{`\x1C\xA9\xA7\x8D\x0E-\xD5\x02I\xB8\x82]B\xA2T\xA7\xB9\x18\xDB\xCA\x86]\xCC>\xB4\xC59\xB8`\xAD\x84\x17\x94\xBCg\xD1\xDB@\x1E\x93o\x0Fo?\x00\xDF\xD2\xD3\x95\x925\xAF%\xC8\x957O\x95\xC2\xD2C0\xF2Ci\xBD\xEE\xB2uZRL\xF9\tY;f\xE2\xD5!w?\xA5\xA93\x96\xBE\xB8\xD3w\x14\xED\xAB[\x94\x0F\x98\xF4\xFB\x80=f/\xDF\xAB\x05\xBD\xDA\x11\x03>\xE7\xC6\xAC-e\xDCb\xE6:\x85!<\xEC\xFF\x82\x82j\x9B\xE1\x05\xD9\x138N\x9C\x0E\xB3{\xD0\xF1\xE9\v7\b\xDF\xBDU\x176&\xFF\xD3W\xC2\xFD\x8D\xFF\x84\x03\x0E\xD87\x83\xC1\xB2\xB1\xF6S\xF19\xA9\xF0\xB2l\xA0r\x0F\xDC\xA1A\ae\xF1\x9D(\r\x97)y\x14\xEFi\xBD\xFE\xBC\xB3\e\xFB\x9B\xC4wTD\xF5\nc\x99\xBDW}lJ\x1A\xC7J0*\x8A\x9F\xD4u\xD7T\xB8\x04\xFDm\xD2\x93\xE5J\x1E\n>\xEF~\xAE\e\x9442\xD6K]\x89Y45\xBC\x9E\"P\xC0)6,)\xAB\f\xED\xF3\x9C\x85\x80\xAD\"\x8C\x8A*\xA7\xCB\xDAz\xCCk\xF8\xA2(C\xDA\xDEB\xE4\x12\xED\xDAa4\xB6\x14\xB9S\xB2\xB8!\xC1\x18eH\xB9\xD5\xF4M\xDEg`\xEE\x9B\xD4\x91\xFCl\x92\x15\xF1\"@\x7F#\x7F\xC1\x10p\xC8%C'\xF3R=\xCD\xD0\xE7|\n\xBB\xB7<\xB6\xEE\xF3X\xA2O9\xFE]+\xB0#\x91\xFA&\xD3\xE4e\x9C4\xA1\xB3\xDF\xA8r\xCF\x8F\xC8\xC3\x92\x04\x02e=T\xD6QO\x88i\x920g\xA4u\x18\a\xBB\xC1\xAAY\x13\xBA\xCDt#<\x9C\x80\x11\xE4N\xA9\xE2!W\xC2\x7Fb\x1D\xBEU\x86\xE0%\x18\xAF=a5\x96\xC4\v\xBF\x88\x86>S\x84\xC8\xEC\x9CR\xABk3\xDA\x7FXh\xA3\at\xF6\xE2\x97\xCF\xB2\x8C\xA3\xDB}b\xC9\x95\x91\xCE3\xC70\xA0\xDD[Sv \x95\n\x96\xEC\x97Ti\xE6\x91\xB9\xE9w\x96f>OH\x03x\x1C\xB4?G\e4k\xC2\x11\xA9\xB4'\xF2\x06\xAA]\xE4\x0F\x93\x98\x84t\xFA\v\xDB*\t\xB9\xDB\xC3\xEA\xF4\x81O4\xD3\xF1]6\xBA\x89\x94\xD6\x1A\x9D\xE1\xB6\xEF\xE25\x10\x1F\x16\x00QK\x06\x8B4\x17%\x95\x85\xAF\x89?^\xE6\xC1+\xAF\xFFK\x04\xE6\xBB_\x81\xCB\x93PU\xF4\x05A\x97\x99\xE7\xF7f\x9C\xD9\xE1%\xA2\xF4\xDD\xD2\xA7J:\xA4\xA3\x8E\x90\xE2\xC5\xF9F\xDAr\xC2\x96B\xEB\xAD\x8F\x84u\xEA\xDF\e\x14Y\xFEp\xAF{nJ\xBF\xE3\xE0\x17\xADRq\xB2k`\xC0\x9D\x92\b\x1D\xFE\x9CKU]\xDD2\xC2\xA8\xA08\xF0\xE2\xD1T\xAF\x97\xE5\xDEl\xC6|Ju\x88-r\xD3C\x16\xC1$\xBB,?\xA2\xF1\x95\xF5\xF6\x00\xDA\x0E]\x8E\x1D\xA3S'c\x91\xAA(\xDF/d2g\xA3\xDD\xEDp\xD8X\xB1\xDA\xD5xfn3\xBB\xD0\x9B;\x02\xDBAI\xDE)\xED7\x17\xDB5\xEEL\x137\x0E\xE7\xDC\xD0M\x98\xE2\x18\f\xE6\x19\xFE\x14\xBF.\xCF9H\ek\xF9\xC5Lz\xB8\xC8\xD3L\x95\v&\x16\fS\xB1c\xB5\xAE\x04S\x8A\x8Cgf!:gr\xBAf\x01\x8FI,\xBA\xDC\r\xAF!v\xA1\xF0)\n\xDC;)\xF9!\x84\x8E\x0F\xCE\x1A\xC89\x1A\xF2(\xA7\xF5Nu\xD6\x19\xCB\x98\xFE\xFD\x80\x89w$i\xEA\n\xA7\xB2\xCD\xDB\xD5\v$\vt\x98C/\x8E\xCF/\x83\xAE\xB3VD\xD2\xE9\xB4\x9E\xEEv\x8AV\xAAq\xAF\x8D\xED\xE4\xEFL;=\xE2\xACOf\x15R\x86WP\xFE\xD7\xA5J\xEDDl\x8B\x1A2ws\xE3udc\xA6I.\xF8p\xAE\x85\xBA\x83%\xFF\xC9\x13\xDB\xDD/v\xD2\x1FR:\x80\xDF\xAFC9\xBC\xA8\xF9i\xFC\xB1(\xCA\x13\xCB\xCFt7\\V\x90:\x13\x82$\x15\x1F\xBD\xB6\xBD>\x15\xEA\xE2K\xCB\xB2\xEF\xA2\xD1\xCD4\xF7\xF9\xCF\xDD\xBF(\xAB\xE9\xBB\x14r\x93\xA2R2\eY\r\xD8\x18<s\xC85\r\xCA\xC1_\xD7^S\xD5./\x18\xD8K\xEF\xE8\x8A\xD1\eg&\xC8\xEB\x94\xB3$dv\"b\xD67\f\xF7\x93\x13mI\xA7\xA8/Y\xC73sl\x884\x9E\xCA@\x04\x818\xAF,e\x85m\x97Hp\xAC-*#\xCC\xDE\x8CVQ\xD8\xE3\xE2\xDE0wp\xCEI%b^<Dq\x8F\x1AZb\xEB\t\xF6{\xA3\xD2\xEE\xCDp\xED\xC7\xADiv\xB0\x9C\xF3\xB5\xEC\x19\xB6\xE7\x95\xA5\x05yFf\x02\xBA]\x1A*x\x06\xE5\xDD\xE0\xC1\\\xDE!\x97\x194\xDE\xFDAPX\x19\x97(\x1C\xB0\x8F\x05\x99]mZ\x14Z\xC8\xFA\xAC\x89n\xA4EC\xF6\xC3\x0Ee\xB0\xD6\x05T\xF2z\xF7\f\xD9\x91p\xD1\xD4\x10\e\xF9\xC1\x962\xFBy\x1D\xDB\x81R\x83\xE0O\xFCF\xCC\xCC`\x06D\xC9\xF1\xD0\x1A0\x04\xA1\xD0\x0E\xEAw\xA6u\xBE\xB0\xE3/2\x9B*\xBC8i\xFBL\rLt\x920\x1E\t\x1D\x0F -\xF9w\x0F!\xCE`m\xFE\xE6\n$\x1D\xC6qp\xA8qq\xD1\xD4\x86\xA8\x83\x02\xA3\x02\x81\x83TI\x86\xBB\x12\xC0*\f\xF3^\x95\x0Ek\xFB2\xB1\xF2\x81\xBD\xC4^\x14\xFF\xF3\xBETv\xF6[\a\x83W\xB7WT5\xD0\xC1mV\vZ\x95\xF5\xDC\xAB\x97<b\x92N\xA3\x80\xF8\xDEU\xA7J\x81-*\xB4\x91\x96i\x00\xB7\n\xA9S\xF5G\xBDv\x9A\xCC\xA1\xC2P\x97\xDCc\xAC3x\xAC\x02\x17\xE0)!\xD2\x03\x90E\x1C\x04\a\x1E\x06a\x15\xBE\x8Fz\xDB_\xC5u|\xF3`\x1F#\x99\x91\x16\x00\xDDF\xD0\x82\x92\xF6\xCA3W\xAF\xA0\xD4a\xBF\xC7\x81QIm\xEE'\xA0\x9F\xBF\xCE\xA0\x9FmZ\t\xEF\x89\xEA2+\xCBp\x87\x11b\vP=\xFB\xB3\xD9\xE9\xD2\xDE\x1D\fVS\xD6\xF4NO\xF7\xC7bt>\xA8\xAE\xF0pf\xD6\t\xA8v\xFE\x00\x03 \x84V\xB6\x88%s\xB3\xA9\xDBv-\x85$\xBF\x192\xD7\xA9XY\xF9Q'\x1E>\xB2>\\y,\x84B;\x03\x16#\xFBY\xF2\xDA }\x8D\r\"M\x9D 8N\x9C,E\x8A\x16\xF9\xA8\xFB\x87\xFA\xC7\xA0/\r\x1Ed\xDE\xC6\xDCArD\x13\xD3\xD4\xFA\x89\xCA\n\xFF$\xD9\xCEB\xD4w\x8A1\x9Dm\xDDU\x18f\xCFz\xDDD\x9Dd\xFC\xA0\x95\xD1\xCC!\xA0\xE2J\x006\xF8\xE3\xF11?.U\xA2\xF2>\x05\xE7\xAD\x8BY\xCB\xF8\x89\xBB:\x17\xC8N\xDD['{\a\xF1\x1Ec:]\xAE\x100\xD2\x9E\x18\xF3X\x8C\x8EWH\x94\ry\xECf\x8B>\x1C\x90p\xEF\xF2r\xCFq\x7F\xD6\x86\xDF\x17;\xC0\x91\x9A\xEF%\xBB\xF4\x03n\xC5\x05\xE5*\xAE\xFD\x03\x94\xB3\xA81y\xB1]\xC9,4\xCA\xC4\xA9\xCEn\xFB\xD5\x9F\x8C\xF4\xFB\xB3M\"\xCA7\xE6\x16<+\xEB\xD0\x8A\x88\xB3\x17\x9C^\xEC6\xAA\x0EQ\xDA\xED+\xB6s\xD0\xE8\xB5k(%\x95~\x10z5\x86o\xE0F]\x9EB\xAD\x8D\x15g\xF4^\xE6lKQ\xD8Q\xC36\x1A\x82\xF1\xD1\xB1Q\xC5X\xF8\x84\xE8\xCC\xA0\x9B\fC\xCC\x10,\xC1{_{\xB5\x1DR( 8\x9B'8\xB4\xCD\xFFf\x8F\b\x959\xD4t\xCEH\xDF\x1FQ\xF3s\xE9\xBB\xCC=\xD4\x96(\x86\xE5\xDFt\xD7_\xA3A\xFF\x8B\xDAE\xEF#M\xDDH\x03SvHy;\x88d\xBE\x9D<\x1A\xF6\xFD|;\xE9\xB4\xCF$\a\xE6bF\x851\n\x8A=4\x95r50\x81\x89T4\x80\xA7\xABz\xDA/\xFF\xAE\xEF\xA5;\xACq\x03\e#E\x13\x06\xA6zD\xD0\xDB}+\xCF\x8Fp\x1E\x10AI\xE5\v^\xF2\xF7X\xA2HIv\xDB\xBB\xFC\xDF9\xD6t[\x94\xF7\xD9\xFE\x91\xD8\xFEZ\xC5C\x0EZ\x0F\xFF\x96\xB6\xF2~\x01'4\xAA\xA9\xD8\x11a\xD0\x9F%\xB9\xD7_\xE4\x8D0\xAAr\x80~\x10\xE5t\xC7of~\xBC\xE2pImR\xA4\xAB\xD2\xDCkx\x19\x96\xFDG\xDA\x02\x1F\xD1,\x7F\xA4C1\xC7\x95\v\x02r;\xA1^!\x90\x9B]+_\xC1\x11\x14\x13\xE8\xEE\xD3\x06\x11Fq\xC2dB\xBF}\x16c\xB4C\xAB\xA6\xDA\xD4\xD0\xFB\x86\xA6\x9B4\xF0\x85|J\xA9ES\xA3[\xCF\x0E)\"\xFA\x90\x17\x82\x82r\xB3\xD5LVJ\xD7\f=\xB1S\x9E\n=\xE3\x9B+k(\xFE\x8Eh\x1DI\xDE9\x96\xAEVlT\xB4\x97\x04j\x92S\xBD+\xD7\xB9u\xAE\xD2L\xD8\xA1\xC3\xCE\xD66n\xCEXO=\xD6\xA4s\xE4\xDB\x8F\ewz\x93\xB7\x15x\x96\xA2\xDB\xA1\x9A\x10\x92\xE1\xCE\xE7\xF5\xDA\x8E\xE50\x81\xC2@\x81\xF8\xFBru\x9Co\xF8O]\x82\x15H-\x93\xF8\xC5g\x13R\xB9\xCF',\xC1\x93\xD97\xEF^w\xB0M\xD4\x8D\xE6@\x85\xED\x9E\xE5\x9EG]\xA5\xDF\f\xE7H\xC6\xCAJ]\xE4\x9C\xE0\x9A\xB1_3%\xB7\x93\xA7\x9A\xE1\xA3H!AU\xED\xDD<a\xBB\xA7\xC6\x99_\xB1\x8D\x8Aty2\xBC\xC1\xC3P\xFE\x84B8\xD9\xBA\xD2\x81+0\xF6\x05\x97\xD4\x8D\xD5h\x94I\xE2\x1CDMu\x96\xFE\xB8\x93,At\xDE\xE6[\x01\xEFh\xB6\xB7\x8F\xB2\x11/\xEA\xC7\x1E\xCB\xD44\xF8\x02\xFF\r\xEED\xA5\xAA7$<\xCCr\xAC\xBFJe\x8C\xB6\x13T\xDBQZ/{0\x96\xCDuc\xBA\xD3\xB2(\xA8\xC6-Q$}\xF3\x82\xA6%\x18d\xDF\xD8\xE6\x81v1\xA3\rl\xB9\x14\xF8%\x87|\x10'\xEAj\x15?\xF9\xE8\xF8\xBD\x80\#{\xCFAD\xB16\xDF|\xAFFp\xD47\xEA\x95\xA3\xAC\x92v\xDD\x9E[\x91\t\xF7\xD9%\xCC).\eG\t\xA8\x83\xE9\xEEl\xAE\x93K\rG\x80\xF4v\b'\xAB\xF3c\"\xDB\xA9e\xD1\xF5\x1F6Q\x15k\x10a\xFA\xCEG=\xDC\xA8Dr\xDB%\xA23Nt\xC2\xEF\x7F\xF9\x14\x87q\x06ih\xB7;\xA9\x1F4\x05\xC9Qm\xDC\xD3\xCC0\\\\<\xF4\x9FL\xEE\x84Wj$F\x92\x1D\xAF\xC7\x16\xA3\xB4$F\x88.&\x11\x98\x94\xB9\x94C\x96\xA4\xBE$a\x8B\x1F4C\x892MotV\x82\xB0\xEF\r.Fh)b\x1D\xD4eP\nt_\xC95\xBE\xE0#!7\xC6k9zo\x03\xC3s\x05\xC5\xF8E\xC4p\xD0\xEA\"^\v\xFE\x98|\a\xC2\xDA\xD1\xF1\x0F\x85<\xDC9\xB9\x0E\x8F@\xB3\xB9c\x03\x9A\xE7\xD5U\n\xA9\xE0\xD9\xD4\xD0\xD4\x90\xF6\xA9\xA3M\xD6\xBCom \xC2\xDBe9\xA3\xEF\xC2q\xC57\xB5hTr\xED\xCE\xED^\xF0w\xAC\xE7\x91Z\x11\x9E\x91\x87\x133L\xB6/D\xE6\xF1aN\xF0h\xA8\x1F\x8B\xD3\f\xA8\xFE\x87\xBDh$\x94\x91\xB8,\xB7\x1C\xCE\xE3SP4\xD1B\v\x13\xBA8\\\xFAi\x82\\\x9E\xBC.\xCE<W\xFF\x1CL\r\xD9\xCA\xED\e!K\xD2\x12\"</\x1Eo\x16\x1C\xB2\x87\x12p0\t3\xEC?s\xD3\xB5\xE93\x15ne\x15G\xAE\xCB\xD1\xE2P\xDFG\x82\x1D\x87s\x1Fm\xC8k\xD8\xEC\xDF\xFA\xDB\xAB\xDF\x90\xB6\f\xE3\xE5*\xB8\xB8t\x81HgH\xAD\xCB\xA6X\x99F?5/\e\xFA\xEC\xBFQ\xC6WU\t\x1A\xBD\xF1\xA1\x87\xEE\x96\xC6Xd\xDDDY\xFC\xCA\"\n9V%\ep\xEF\xE0\x11\v\xA0\xE4S\x850\xFDd\xC9\xA3\e>\x18\x94\xEC<l\x92\xECb\x88m\xCE\x1E\xCE\x94\xEC\xA3\v\x11nK.\x19\x16\xE9@L\xF3\x8Cr\xF7B\xC5\xB4S\xED\xF5JR7\xC7\xB2\xDC\xBB9\xA5X\"m\xDF\x85\xD7\x05Y\xD0\xF3\x00b\x17\v\xD1m}\x89Os\xEA$j\xC9W\xDD\x16Z\xEC\x19\x88\xA7Wn\xB5W\x9D\x97\xD7c\x81\x9F\xDA@\x8A:M\xA9TN\xE6\x8B\xB1,\xFA\x17\xC2t\x13\xA7[\vlP\x10\xA5\xB6\xD9t\x88\xE7T\xC2\xCAE\xEC\xCCb\xEF\xF1\b\x82\x91\x0F\x97\xB0\x00\xF3\x11\x13\xBAf\xB2#\xE9swi\xD1\xA1\x90\xE9\\7\xAA\xE1S\xAE\x16\xC2\xDF\xB4M\xC4\xFE\x01\xFD;\xB7=\xD9:\xF4\xFB'S\x14\x8E\x93\xE6v\xF9`3\xAE\v\xAEB\xED\xED\tp\xEA%\xFAy\xC9\xAFG\xF3P\x15\xB8\vPY\x060\xDCt\x01\x92D\xDCa\x9E\x1C}!\xC0\xBA\x85\xADa\xD0\xD7\xD3`\xA6\xF4\x91\x00\xDAA\x9DtX\xD6\xC22\x9A\xBF\x9A\x94\xED$v\xEB\x90\xBAEd\x11\xB6\xFE\xDC\xF9\xD4\xBE\x8D\x83i\x90n}\xC7Io\xCC\xCC\xAA}\xA0\xF96!0\xD6#\x8F\x01\x16\x19]\xEFv\xA4+&#\xC3\xA7;\xDD\xD9}2j\n\x89@\x9F\xDA\xBB\xEF-\xB3\xE0dZ\x06W!\xF0R$F\"\xEAm\xF3\x88\xCE\ve\xE7\x97\x16\xFA#T\x15\t\x91p\v\xF3\x1F\xB2\x9A\"B\x88^3A\x9D\xA6\x93\x8A\xD6~\xF6\xA8\xECe\x10R\xCCK\xB6\x06\xC6-\x89xren\x96\xEE\xBFW,\xE6\xE8\x97\x82q\xDAl\xB1\xB7\"#\x05\xC9\xC7\x96\xCA\x10\xC0\xB5\xC9\xEB\xB4\xC2\x9DE\x06\xEE\xED\xFB\xF9H<\x9Eg\x9B\f\xEF\x1Ak\xAB\f\x1A\xA7\xBFgH\xA7'\xEFTm@|+\xD5\xE3t\xD8\x9Bl\xF8\xE7\xCEw!\x14\xD5FA\xF7\x11\xFA\xE7-\xC90\x9B\xA5\x10\xBC\x12\xEC\x9B\xD0\x8B1\xF2\xE3\x83\x9Ath\xB4\xA4\xF8`ZO\xBD\x87\xF7\x97\x81B\x7F\xBCB\xA7v\xA5.x\x82\xE3\xDE\x17\xF3g\xB3[\xC1\xE71\x95\xCB\xB4\xFE\x00\xD8\xEF\x15$H\xCEeU\x91de\x1D\xEEs\x922]\v\xF7#q\x16HJ\xC0e\a\xFC\xD8)\xF35A\x10<z{L\x15\\\xA3\x9F\xCB\xD99\x8D\xC8g\x8AL\xCC\f\x89\x04\xF2\x1E\xC2\x98\x87\x00\xB2\xE1\x9DMP\"R.\xB6b8\xA5\x16\x14\x9Fm\xBC\xEA\xFC\xF1\xB4u0\x03\x82\xCDL\xE9\xB6\xB3\x19X\x87\x99}F?tM\x94\xC6\xB8j\x03\x96\xE7T\xB5N\xB7\v\xC0\r\xD3\x93\x06\xA0\xD7[v\xD7K\x0E[!\r\xE5\x9D\x0F\xE2K\xDF\x8C/\x1AE\xE0\xF0t}\x9D\x81\x02Fb5\x8A\xF5\x0E\xC8\xA4hS\x94L:\xFE\x99\x15O\v<\xA3\x98\x985\x06$\x1E\xB0\xC0:H\x05\x90\x8C\x7F|\x1E\xE6\xC4\x90\e\x1D\xB8I\xB4\x01\xEB\xEC\x17o.\xE3\xEB\xDA'n\x8F\xB6`\xD6\x9C\xD5p \xFF\xA2\x1DY_\xBE\xA1p\xD8\xD2\xFD\xA8\x8E\x9E\xE1\x8BZ\x8F^P\x19\xF1\xA0i\xE6\x9D]\xAB\x7F\xBA\xE5s\xE7\a%\x85\x1E\eTJl\xD4\v\xE4\x06\x93\xC0\x93\xDD1\xCC/6V\xC1\xB6\x9B$m\xC6\xCF\xD1\xEE\xB0\xF1\x8D\xE1g\xB9i\x9A\xB5\xAA \x88\bM\xEF\x18\xF7U\xD9\\2U\xCE\xB9\x9D\x17L%w\x16\x87}f\xBB\xE3!3\xB2\xEB\xEF\x8Cm\xC3\xAE\xDB\xE0\xDA#\xAB\x81\xD0\xE6\x9Bj\xD9C\b>\x94\x9E\xB4>H\xC46c\xD0;@\x9B\xBB\x01k\xBB\x17uuI\xC3\x8D\xD5Q\x17*uj\x03\xA54\xEB\xD4N\xC6\e\xD8\x83&HR\x12:06\xDB\x17\x1F!\xB8p\xE2\x7F\xAA7\x17\xD0\xF7\x05<3F\xFC\xFE\xC0oZL\xDD\xB6\xAD?\xEF\xA0O\x8A\x9E\xCC[&\x1A\xB3=\xCB\xA8/\x1E\t$\x89\xCF\xBF\x90;\xFF\x92%Y\xED\x8C\xF5\x17\xB5\xE7r-x\xEC\"\xD6\xC5\xFF\r%\xF1\x98\xDA_P\x90\xAA\x9F\x0F/de\x86\xCBl\xB7\xCE\xD8\x80wj\xCD\x1E\x9D\x15\"\xDC\xB4\xF0\xA3LhYEJ\x9D\x0F\xC9]\xC6\xD8\x13\x87\x1Aw#\xC9\x1FL\xD3l@\xBC\xF1\b\xC4?\x9DwF\e\xD2\xCB\xB1\xB0O\\\x9E\xF4\a.S\xD0\xD9k$w\xE8}\x99\xC5M\v\xC4\x90\xC3\xE1v\x8C\xA0\xB5\x8F3Z\x1F\x00\xB3\x0E\x9E\x99\x94\xFB\x88\fpV\xAE\xD8&\xF9l\x9A\xC8w= \x88\x9CxR\xE1\xFE\xA5\x83ioH\x87\xF7\xFCC\xC8\x88\xD6\x1F\xE1u\x9A\x9D\xF9\xFC\x88\xFE\x9Dt\xA0\x96S)#e\x96#\bd-\xF9\xB0\xA2\xC2\x14\xC7\xAD\xFA\x80\xCC\xAF\x18Q\xB3\xA4N9\xA9\x18\xC8\xAE\x89\x91M\x95!/\x82\xDAo\xAA#[e\xDA\xA2\x9F\x14mL\x0E\xFD\xD9/W\x01s\x9B~\x89\xB0^\xBAs`G\xEF\xDF\xA1&=4\xC8\xB0\x95Kh\x0FV\x87\xD9\xD1b\x05\ey\xF4\xB7\xDA\xC2)C\xB2\xF5\xED\x95\x83\xFE\x1F58\xF9\xBA\xC7N/:i\xDA\xCF\xA5\xEC\xECV\xF2\xE7\x8E(Wi\xBD\xFF\xA4\x17-\xD3\xF2\xB8^\xF6\x8F\xF0?\xF4PJ\x8E#\xED\xF3\x81\xE7\xBDyE\xCA\x0F\n\xA2i\xFBA\xAD\x7F\xA6\x9C\xE2\xBA\xDF\x8A\e\xE3 U\x8Brr\xFD\xC9\x8F\x87\xE6L\x7Fk6\xDA\xD1\xB9)\xF7\xB4\xA1.H\xC07\x9Ej\xD7\a&{\x04\xC3\xD5\xD1\xF2\xDA\xD2\xE9\x91#\xC4\x94\x18\xFD\b\xAD\xBA\x06^\xDD\xED\xD4\x8D\xF6\x95V4\x80\xB9\xEAW\xF8r\xDD\xA6\x85\xA2\xA5\xAB\xE2\xC2\xC4b\x92>Dh\xFF\x80Q P\xA0\xBF\xEFw\x1E}E\xB6O\xAA\xC24!\xA6\xE3\xBC\x98\x8EGm'?\xFAP\xE7\xF0g\v\xEF\x19\">z\xE9v9OP)\xFA`\xAE9\xAA\xB5\xCC.Pw\x8A\x87|\x9C\xDB\xAD\a*s\xDB\xBDt?\xE3\n_\x8B\x19\xF4\x91\x05\xA7\x87\a\x9D\xEAh\x1C\xED\x99m\xDF\xEC\xEB]\xB2B\x8BW*|%,O\xD4^\xF2\xD4\xCB\x8C\xAA\xA0\xA89\x02Bi\xBC\xC02\xDEA\xA0\xA3*52\x12l\x86\xB1r\x91=at\xAAGg\xBE\xB6\xA7\x96%\n\xA6d\x04\x8C\x11\"\xE9\x832f\xDD\xD4\xFBT\x00\xB4\xE0\xBEo\xBF\xB1PLS\xEEmQ\e\xE8\x90\xD4 \xB0\xA1\xFCGUL{* \xB6\x83\xA0\xB7\x1D\x0E\x86\x12\xFE\xF3\xD5z\xBF\xDCZX\x8D\xBBHOc\xD5\xCB\xF7\x9A\x86\xC1X\x06=\xC1CD8\x97\x9AV\xB3/\xFE\xB6\xEDRS\x8C,\xEBw\xA9\x1C\xC31\xE8$M\xA1\xE0\x81\x05\xC7\xF8\xBFG\x95,J\t%\xF7{\xC1\xD2\x9CZ\xD2\xF0X\x86\x01\\\xBDi\xFE$n\x874\xA2@\xAF\xDC\xA8\xD8Ua\x19#\xD6\x96\xFC\x18\xF7.\x89\xEA\xEB\xBAe\xBC\xD2\x02\f\xE4\xCC\xED*\xC0)\x93\xC6\xE5\xDB\xFAo\xA1;[\x1E\xA1\xE5\xE1\xA2\xCE\x92\x13_`\xD0\x01\xFA<\xB2y\xEE/\x86\"y\x82\xA5H h*\xA9\x97\xF2\xD8\xD8u(\xD1u\xFB\x83\xA7\xE5lvT\xA111\xB5\xF8N\x94\bQ&t\xC6N\xB7\\\xB9@(\xAD\xD9\xA9Q\x8B\x88c\xC2\xA8l\xB3\xD1\b\xA4!z\xA0_R\xF7\x8B\xE1H\x82K=\x9D\xE6\xCEN2}K\xA3;\x97\xD6\xCF\xCF\x88\xAF(\xA0\x9D\x13\xA8c\xDE\x8A\xF4\xB6[\xB2\xC6\xD2eS\xD7\xADu\xA4\xD2v\xD2\x9E\x7F|\xA7\t\xC7\x11y\x9Bo\x95\f\xAA\x95\x19\x9D\x16V#\x7F:0\xE1\x1C\r\x9B\x1F\xEFz\xA6x\xD8\xC8p9j\xF4\xB6\f=Q\xA0\xEB47\x90\xA4\x13\xD0\xFA\x1E\xAF\x89ouVG\x8A\xFD+\xDC\xE1\x10\x19o&\xEB\x8D\t\x9B2*\xDB\xAE\x16{{\xF0_W2\xBF\xBC\xCE\x033\xF6]Cb\xB5\xAFZ\x05\xAF\x10\x12\xDFsB\xD9\xEF\xB0#\xA4\x7F\x0E}\x1AC\xB79\xC4\xDD\x85\x9E\xFE\xB4E\xAE%Z#H3o\x9B3N9Ne\x13\x88\xAA\xBF\xCE\xD5\xE8g\xE1g\xE2\xA9\xCE\xCC\x8E]\xA5.\xFF\xCE\xD7\xC8\x90 \x8E\x02\x00\xCF,\x14\xBE\xEB2\xDD'\x03\xB8N\x9F5\xB1\x9Fl<\xE3\x86\xA8t#\xB8'\xB5Ig\\\xC4\x93f\xE1$\xE3F\f\xC8\x82KB\xF5'\xA9\x8Fz\x16\xBA\xE1\x1C\x8E2/\x83\x94\xBE\xCFh$\xE2g\xACf\x9A-\x85\xDA\x1F\xE6{\xDE[\xE5r\x8A>\xAC\xD7C\x99=\xDAnU?\x93|5\xFF\xB4\xF5/,\x8D^xOE\xA2\xC8<Z\xFE@\x9F\b\xC1K\x13\xCF\xB0\xB6Z\xA0\xCDR\x93ha\x0F>\xB3\xF75\xC6\xD0\xE9\x90\x9E\x80L-\xA6jt\xB7\x10\xFF\xED\xC4\x0F\xD8T\xA9+\x8F_\x14u\x17\xF6Cp\x9F\x13\xBB,\xA0\x87\t\xCCnM+8s\xBE\x93\xB1\x96\xA0,\n\xF4m\x8A\x80\x9C\xF6= \xB2\xAE\"$\t0\xC2\xDA\xDA]\xBC\x91\xD6I\xA4\xC5\x91\x1Cw\xA4@\xA5\xC7Km]\xC64\x95\xD1\x16\xD2\b\xBA\xB1\xE2\"lfV\x88\x04$n)Wb\xD5\b\xFC\x85\xEE>\\\x8B\xD1\x0F\xEDV.\x94\xEBGi&\xCF\xD9\xD9\xB8N\xCA\xF0\xA1\x7F\xE78G7\x1C\xB43\x10\xB9\xAC[-\x82\xC9\xAC\x17\xAF\xFFQ\xD8\xC45\xF7\xBD(1S0\xE2X4\xBE\xF6X81\x9E\xA7Yod\xAFvi&\xD0I\xCCf\t\xB7\xD0\xB2\xD5~\xC9\x84Y\x1E\xC4\xC7\x81\xC9U\xAFgnk\x0F\xD0\x15\x0E83\x96\x89A\x00\xCEJlZ\xD7\xD4\xCFD7\xD3\x02\xC5<t!q\x8B\x1D\a\n!\xBA\x87b\xA0\x06/6\xC4\x1Ed\xDAk\xE0\xC1O\x91\xE6\x02\xC3\xA7\xF9\xA4\xF5\xCC\xCA\xC7-\x06\xA2\xEDL\x86\xD4a\n\x152J\xD9y_\xB4\xD7y\xD0\xDC\xA8\xE2R4\xF9\x9Dk\x1D\x18'~s\x0ExX\x9C:'\xDE\xE9\xA6\xDEfy\x8A\xD0$0\xE3C\x88h\xC3\xFA!N\xF7I\xC6\xD7\x97h\x9F\xCA\xAA;\xBA\x19\x95\xF0:\xF4\xED\x17\xE5\x9C}!!\xDF\xFF:a\\\eO<*/\xA2\x9AB\x8C\xB8t\x83\xC4\xAD\x1F\xC9zZ9\xAF\x9E\xC6J\xC5Y\xB0\xA2A`\x7F\xEC\x00\xA6dK\x1Dtrc\xC5\xDAU\e\x8C\xB0f'\b\xD2\x9E\x9B\xBFE\xCF(\xBEx\xF9\x95\\\x8B\xA1\xA8 \x97\x9F\xA9R\x80\x82\xE43\xCD\xF6\x8E\xAB(\a\x9F\x9A\x11\xEC\xBA\xA5\xD8m\x9A\xA5,\x8B\xB0k0\xFF\xB4\xBD\xE66\xB2\xA8!\x0F\xBAH\x14\\\x133 \xEBX\x81\xEB\x0F\x05[\x00\a\xDFr\xBA^\"\x0E\xD3s\x18\xB8\xBE0E\x9A<\xDFCY@\xD7R\xDEu]7\x97\x02\xA2\xD9\x15\xFB\xB6\x8F\xF7\x8D\tB[\xCA\xCE\x05~;YH\"\x87\xFF\xD80\xD4+\x9B,\xAF5\xD9B\xF4\x83p]\xAFm\b,\xCC3*\x00\xBC\x92\x17\x8D\xB9\xAB\xB7\x06y\xDA#\xF2\xA8\xB2\x1C\xE2\xA1;7\x82u\x04\xF9\xA7\b\x85\xAF@\xC5\xE3\xB5\xE0}\x9D\#@\x1D\xD9\xC9\xB7\xA8\xB2\xD1\xD5%\x06\" F\x98\xD5\xF9\xF1.\xEB\xDF\x98\x8A\xED\xCD\b\xFB\xCD\xF1c\x9ADd\xAE\xA7\x94\xCFY\xF1`\xD6\x06\xED\xAC\xBD\xFF\x82\xEA\x9E\xE2\x13\xBDn\x99J\x04\xCC[m\nd8\x84\xB0\xBD\xBB\x9A\x18\x17z\xF9\x8F8\xF9\xFF5H\n\xB9`d\x8A\xD2c\xA7\x8C\xEBr8H\xF2<\x90I\xBF\x88\xBE\xCF\xAD\xB1\xBB,\x0E\x8FJ\xAE\xC4\xDF\x8E\xAB\xC30\xCFk\xD2\xFE\x1F'P\xB9\x83\x06\xE7\xD2\vr\x14\xD6\xE8\x12\xC7\xDC?\xEA\xAA\xE1F\xFB\xB9\xE7\x14FA\xEC\xD6\xC69\xF22~\xE7\xF7ho~\xFD?\x97\xC4\x02\x8A\xF6\xA8\a\x84\x8C\x96\f\xC0W\xC3\x11\xC1X\x99\x16\xC0\x8E\xE1\e\x9A"

# inflate compressed data
937.times do |counter|
    data = Zlib::inflate(data)
end

# request input
puts "Please input two numbers, each on its own line, to add."

# run data code
eval(data)
```

And where did I get that enormous string, you ask? This is the program I used to generate it:

```
require 'zlib'
code = 'a,b=gets.to_i,gets.to_i;p a+b'
oldcode = nil
count = -1
until code.inspect.length > 29000; oldcode = code; code = Zlib::deflate code; count += 1; end
File.open(ARGV.shift, 'w') do |f| f.puts oldcode.inspect; end
puts count
```

Yay for "compression"! :P

As you can see, I set the string's length limit to 29000, which is just under the length limit for Stack Exchange posts, but I could make that as high as I wanted to.

Answer (score 10):

## C (via perl) - 170,141,183,381,241,069,554,076,045,499,751,727,125 (that's 1.70141183381241e+38) for 32-bit unsigned inputs

My philosophy is that, when implementing addition from scratch, it is not wise to rely on precomputed costants like 2, 3, 7 or 65535! 0 and 1 should be the only constants we need, right?

Therefore, I don't precompute any constants - I calculate them on the fly, as seen below! To support 8-bit signed integer input, you'll need source code of length 20,461,843 non-whitespace characters. To implement 32-bit signed integer input, you'll need source code of length 1.70141183381241e+38 ;-)

Ready for a small snippet of the 8-bit signed integer code? Here you are:

```
int add(int i, int j) {
  if (i == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) {
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1;
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1;
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1;
    ...
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return -1-1-1;
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return -1-1;
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return -1;
  }
  if (i == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) {
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1;
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1;
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1;
    ...
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return -1-1;
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return -1;
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return 0;
  }
  if (i == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) {
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1;
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1;
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1;
    ...
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return -1;
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return 0;
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return 1;
  }

  ...

  if (i == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) {
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return -1-1-1;
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return -1-1;
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return -1;
    ...
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
  }
  if (i == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) {
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return -1-1;
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return -1;
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return 0;
    ...
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
  }
  if (i == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) {
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return -1;
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return 0;
    if (j == -1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1) return 1;
    ...
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
    if (j == 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1) return 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1;
  }
}
```

Note that this code is golfed somewhat - I don't say eg:

```
if(x==1 and y==1) ...
if(x==1 and y==1+1) ...
if(x==1 and y==1+1+1) ...
```

No need to check if x is equal to one a each time, right? So my code is far more efficient† and concise†, and does this instead:

```
if(x==1) {
  if(y==1) ...
  if(y==1+1) ...
  if(y==1+1+1) ...
}
```

I could certainly extend the code-length further by changing to the less concise method =)

And here's the source code I used to generate these monstrosities, but be careful - representing a 24-bit integer in this format (33MB each) results in perl eating over 1GB of memory on my machine. If you have more than 512GB of memory at your disposal, you should be able to go ahead and try it with 32-bit integers =)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($MININT, $MAXINT);
my $abbrev;
if($ARGV[0] =~ /-a(?:=(\d+))?/) {
  $abbrev = defined $1 ? $1 : 3;
  shift @ARGV;
}
if($ARGV[0] =~ /^(\d+)([su]?)$/ && !defined $ARGV[1]) {
  my $unsigned = $2 && $2 eq "u"; #default to signed
  my $bits = $1;
  my $range = 2**$bits;
  $MININT = $unsigned ? 0          : 2**($bits-1)-$range;
  $MAXINT = $unsigned ? $range - 1 : 2**($bits-1)-1;
} else {
  $MININT = shift @ARGV;
  $MAXINT = shift @ARGV;
}

sub componentize {
  my $x = shift;
  return $x < 0 ? "-1" x abs($x) :
         $x > 0 ? "1".("+1"x abs($x-1)) :
         0;
}

my @range = $abbrev ? ($MININT..($MININT+$abbrev), "x", ($MAXINT-$abbrev)..$MAXINT)
                    : ($MININT..$MAXINT);

my $indent="  ";
print "int add(int i, int j) {\n";
for my $i (@range) {
  if($i eq "x") { print "$indent...\n"; next };
  print "${indent}if (i == ".componentize($i).") {\n";
  for my $j (@range) {
    if($j eq "x") { print "$indent$indent...\n"; next };
    print "${indent}${indent}if (j == ".componentize($j).") return ".componentize($i+$j).";\n";
  }
  print "$indent}\n";
}
print "}\n";
```

Whew, that's it =)

Comment: † in case you missed it, that was sarcasm =)

Answer (score 9):

### PHP - 1299

The rules don't prohibit using external libraries so here is the code using [SimplePHPEasyPlus](https://github.com/Herzult/SimplePHPEasyPlus):

```
use SimplePHPEasyPlus\Number\NumberCollection;
use SimplePHPEasyPlus\Number\SimpleNumber;
use SimplePHPEasyPlus\Number\CollectionItemNumberProxy;
use SimplePHPEasyPlus\Parser\SimpleNumberStringParser;
use SimplePHPEasyPlus\Iterator\CallbackIterator;
use SimplePHPEasyPlus\Operator\AdditionOperator;
use SimplePHPEasyPlus\Operation\ArithmeticOperation;
use SimplePHPEasyPlus\Operation\OperationStream;
use SimplePHPEasyPlus\Engine;
use SimplePHPEasyPlus\Calcul\Calcul;
use SimplePHPEasyPlus\Calcul\CalculRunner;


$numberCollection = new NumberCollection();

$numberParser = new SimpleNumberStringParser();

$firstParsedNumber = $numberParser->parse('1');
$firstNumber = new SimpleNumber($firstParsedNumber);
$firstNumberProxy = new CollectionItemNumberProxy($firstNumber);

$numberCollection->add($firstNumberProxy);

$secondParsedNumber = $numberParser->parse('1');
$secondNumber = new SimpleNumber($secondParsedNumber);
$secondNumberProxy = new CollectionItemNumberProxy($secondNumber);

$numberCollection->add($secondNumberProxy);

$addition = new AdditionOperator('SimplePHPEasyPlus\Number\SimpleNumber');

$operation = new ArithmeticOperation($addition);

$engine = new Engine($operation);

$calcul = new Calcul($engine, $numberCollection);

$runner = new CalculRunner();

$runner->run($calcul);

$result = $calcul->getResult();
$numericResult = $result->getValue(); // 2
```

Comment: I am truly interested in why that library was written.

Comment: @marczellm Maybe for an earlier code-bowling challenge.

Answer (score 7):

## Java - 2406 (3220 with whitespace)

We all know that computers are good at handling bits and not so good at everything else. Therefore my program perform the addition using efficient bitwise addition!

```
/**
 * Solution for PCG22921.
 * 
 * The program adds two natural numbers using efficient bit addition.
 */
public class PCG22921 {
    /**
     * Contains the program.
     * 
     * @param   args    Exactly two integer numbers.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // check whether sane arguments were given
        if (args.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must provide exactly two numbers");
        }

        // transform the arguments into integer
        int number1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int number2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        // convert number1 into bits
        String bits1 = "";
        while (number1 > 0) {
            bits1 = (number1 % 2) + bits1;
            number1 = number1 / 2;
        }

        // convert number2 into bits
        String bits2 = "";
        while (number2 > 0) {
            bits2 = (number2 % 2) + bits2;
            number2 = number2 / 2;
        }

        // ensure both numbers have the same length
        while (bits1.length() < bits2.length()) {
            bits1 = "0" + bits1;
        }
        while (bits2.length() < bits1.length()) {
            bits2 = "0" + bits2;
        }

        // stores whether the last addition overflowed
        boolean overflow = false;

        // bits of the result
        String resultBits = "";

        // keep adding until the bits are empty
        while (bits1.length() > 0) {
            // grab the last bit of each number
            char lastBit1 = bits1.charAt(bits1.length() - 1);
            char lastBit2 = bits2.charAt(bits2.length() - 1);

            // Quick lookup table to speed up addition!
            if (lastBit1 == '1' && lastBit2 == '1' && overflow) {
                resultBits = "1" + resultBits;
                overflow = true;
            }
            else if (lastBit1 == '1' && lastBit2 == '1' && !overflow) {
                resultBits = "0" + resultBits;
                overflow = true;
            }
            else if (lastBit1 == '1' && lastBit2 == '0' && overflow) {
                resultBits = "0" + resultBits;
                overflow = true;
            }
            else if (lastBit1 == '0' && lastBit2 == '1' && overflow) {
                resultBits = "0" + resultBits;
                overflow = true;
            }
            else if (lastBit1 == '1' && lastBit2 == '0' && !overflow) {
                resultBits = "1" + resultBits;
                overflow = false;
            }
            else if (lastBit1 == '0' && lastBit2 == '1' && !overflow) {
                resultBits = "1" + resultBits;
                overflow = false;
            }
            else if (lastBit1 == '0' && lastBit2 == '0' && overflow) {
                resultBits = "1" + resultBits;
                overflow = false;
            }
            else if (lastBit1 == '0' && lastBit2 == '0' && !overflow) {
                resultBits = "0" + resultBits;
                overflow = false;
            }
            // error handling is importent
            else throw new RuntimeException("This should not happen");

            // remove the processed bits
            bits1 = bits1.substring(0, bits1.length() - 1);
            bits2 = bits2.substring(0, bits2.length() - 1);
        }
        // check whether there is overflow left
        if (overflow) resultBits = "1" + resultBits;

        // Convert the bits into a result number again
        int result = 0;
        int bitValue = 1;
        while (resultBits.length() > 0) {
            char lastResultBit = resultBits.charAt(resultBits.length() - 1);

            if (lastResultBit == '1') {
                result = result + bitValue;
            }
            resultBits = resultBits.substring(0, resultBits.length() - 1);

            // each bit is twice as worthy as the last one
            bitValue = bitValue * 2;
        }

        // show the result
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add in some error catching to bulk it out...

Comment: I had expected a Java version to use a BitFactory, BitFactoryStrategy, a bunch of XML configuration files, et cetera.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I am usually no Java developer, I chose it because it was pretty verbose compared to other languages.

Answer (score 4):

### Java - <s>309</s> <s>731</s> 759

Not the longest, but could be the most plausible wrong interpretation.

edit: Oops, just noticed this is not [code-trolling](/questions/tagged/code-trolling).

> Adding numbers larger than one bit is done by adding individual bits
>   using a [full-adder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29#Full_adder), which takes as input two bits and a carry-in
>   from the previous stage, and outputs the sum bit and a carry-our bit.
>   For simple addition, the carry-in for the first stage should be zero.

```
public class Adder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int a = 135;
        int b = 87;

        int result = 0;
        int carryIn = 0;

        // Assume 8 bits, so we have 8 full-adders:
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) { // Assume numbers are 8 bits long
            // Get the Nth bits from the numbers
            int bitA = a >> i & 1;
            int bitB = b >> i & 1;

            // Full adder, using the truth table:
            int bitC = 0;
            int carryOut = 0;
            if (bitA == 0 && bitB == 0 && carryIn == 0) {
                bitC = 0;
                carryOut = 0;
            }
            else if (bitA == 0 && bitB == 0 && carryIn == 1) {
                bitC = 1;
                carryOut = 0;
            }
            else if (bitA == 0 && bitB == 1 && carryIn == 0) {
                bitC = 1;
                carryOut = 0;
            }
            else if (bitA == 0 && bitB == 1 && carryIn == 1) {
                bitC = 0;
                carryOut = 1;
            }
            else if (bitA == 1 && bitB == 0 && carryIn == 0) {
                bitC = 1;
                carryOut = 0;
            }
            else if (bitA == 1 && bitB == 0 && carryIn == 1) {
                bitC = 0;
                carryOut = 1;
            }
            else if (bitA == 1 && bitB == 1 && carryIn == 0) {
                bitC = 0;
                carryOut = 1;
            }
            else if (bitA == 1 && bitB == 1 && carryIn == 1) {
                bitC = 1;
                carryOut = 1;
            }

            // Append the bits to the result
            result |= bitC << i;

            // Carry for next stage
            carryIn = carryOut;
        }

        // Verify the result
        System.out.println("Result = " + result + ", CarryOut = " + carryIn);
        System.out.println("Should be: " + (a + b));
    }
}
```

> Result = 222, Carry-out = 0
>   Should be: 222

Comment: In the first few years of my career, I was working in something that looked like a programming language but was actually describing the gates that would be implemented on a chip. This looks painfully familiar... except that I don't think we had anything as elegant as a `for` loop to say "replicate this across all the bits of the input busses". (Imagine a language with procedural syntax and functional execution... where the primary tool for editing it was a highly-procedural representation as flowcharts... what can I say, it was an early effort.)

Answer (score 3):

Python 2.7 (adding the good way)

```
def add(x,y):
    while True:
        a = x & y
        b = x ^ y
        x = a << b & 0xffffffff
        y = b
        if a == 0:
           break
    return b

number_1 = int(raw_input("Please enter a number(1)"))
number_2 = int(raw_input("Please enter a number(2)"))

print "result is: %d" % add(number_1, number_2)
```

credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366706/bitwise-subtraction-in-python

Comment: Is this Python 2?

Comment: @hosch250, yep: It uses the (in python3) unsupported version of print

Comment: @puckipedia Yep, I knew because of `raw_input()`.  I was hinting to the OP that it is good practice to state the language.

Answer (score 2):

```
function add(a, b)
{
    while (b) {
        a ^= b;
        b &= a ^ b;
        b <<= 1;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: What language is this? I assume JavaScript?

Comment: @EriktheGolfer Wow, yes, this must have been one of my earliest submissions.

Answer (score 0):

## C# - 5395

Lets emit [cil](/questions/tagged/cil) code for addition using a dynamic method. Actually I emit code, which in turns emits code to call integer addition. The function `Add()` below builds a dynamic method, which when run builds a dynamic method to call integer addition.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

namespace JA
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int z=Add(1, 2);
        // z = 3
    }

    // Emit MSIL to emit MSIL
    public static int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        Type delegate_type=typeof(Func<int, int, int>);
        DynamicMethod method=new DynamicMethod(typeof(int).ToString()+".op_Addition",
            typeof(int),
            new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }, typeof(Program));
        ILGenerator generator=method.GetILGenerator();

        LocalBuilder method1=generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(DynamicMethod));
        LocalBuilder generator1=generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(ILGenerator));
        LocalBuilder add1=generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(Func<int, int, int>));
        LocalBuilder args1=generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(Type[]));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(int));

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, ".op_Addition");
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat",
                new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(int));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 2);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(Type));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_3);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_3);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(int));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_3);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(int));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_Ref);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_3);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(Program));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj,
            typeof(DynamicMethod).GetConstructor(
                new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(Type), typeof(Type[]), typeof(Type) }));

        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(DynamicMethod).GetMethod("GetILGenerator",
                Type.EmptyTypes));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(int));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("DeclareLocal",
                new Type[] { typeof(Type) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld,
            typeof(OpCodes).GetField("Ldarg_0",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("Emit", new Type[] { typeof(OpCode) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld,
            typeof(OpCodes).GetField("Ldarg_1",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("Emit", new Type[] { typeof(OpCode) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld,
            typeof(OpCodes).GetField("Add",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("Emit", new Type[] { typeof(OpCode) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld,
            typeof(OpCodes).GetField("Stloc_0",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("Emit", new Type[] { typeof(OpCode) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld,
            typeof(OpCodes).GetField("Ldloc_0",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("Emit", new Type[] { typeof(OpCode) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld,
            typeof(OpCodes).GetField("Ret",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(ILGenerator).GetMethod("Emit", new Type[] { typeof(OpCode) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(Func<int, int, int>));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Call,
            typeof(Type).GetMethod("GetTypeFromHandle",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(DynamicMethod).GetMethod("CreateDelegate",
                new Type[] { typeof(Type) }));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Isinst, typeof(Func<int, int, int>));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_2);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_2);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt,
            typeof(Func<int, int, int>).GetMethod("Invoke",
                System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance));
        generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        Func<int, int, int> add2=method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, int>)) as Func<int, int, int>;

        return add2(x, y);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: PS. I tried to emit code that emits code, but in the end I got a `{System.SystemException}: {"JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation."}`

Answer (score 0):

Say you want the code to be longer than n characters. The following code is far longer.

```
public class Add
{
    int main(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + (b/2^1) + (b/2^2) + (b/2^3) ... (b/2^n) + (b/2^n));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## C

```
#include<stdio.h>

int Max(int a,int b)
{
    if(a>b)
    return a;
    else
    return b;
}
int Min(int a,int b)
{
    if(a<b)
    return a;
    else
    return b;
}
int main(void)
{
    int a,b,sum,i,m;
    i=0;
    m = Min(a,b);
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);

    if(Min(a,b) == Max(a,b))
    {
        sum = 2*a;
        printf("%d", sum );
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            i++;
            m++;
        }while(m < Max(a,b));

       

        sum = i + 2 * Min(a,b);
        printf("%d", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Doesn't work well for large numbers, but can be replaced by this

```
#include<stdio.h>

int Max(int a,int b)
{
    if(a>b)
    return a;
    else
    return b;
}
int Min(int a,int b)
{
    if(a<b)
    return a;
    else
    return b;
}
int main(void)
{
    int a,b,sum,i,m;
    i=0;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);

    if(Min(a,b) == Max(a,b))
    {
        sum = 2*a;
        printf("%d", sum );
    }
    else
    {
        i = Max(a,b) - Min(a,b);
        sum = i + 2 * Min(a,b);
        printf("%d", sum);
    }
    return 0;
}
```