# Shortest code to write longest code

Tags: code-challenge

Your challenge is to **create a shortest code** in your language of choice which writes on a **`.txt`** file **the longest code to multiply two numbers by taking two numbers as input and output the answer**.

*NO INPUT NEEDED TO YOUR CODE WHICH IS DOING THE WRITING JOB*!

**The generator code and generated code can be in any languages**

**Do NOT** use unlimited series or progression to make text file big.
**Do NOT** use unnecessary statements to increase the score.

#### SCORING

```
( size of text file generated in bytes )  (without any unnecessary white spaces, tabs or newlines)
-----------------------------------------
     ( size of your code in bytes )
```

## Winner

**Winner** will be chosen **after 1 week** from now with the **highest score**.

**EDIT :** range of input in code multiplying two numbers should be in between -32768 to 32767

Comment: I eventually figured out, but the fact that you use code formatting for the output made it seem like you were looking for the literal string "the longest code to...".

Comment: I think you can just use [this answer by Comintern](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22939/14215), changing the `+` to `*` in the generator program he provides, and you probably already know this, since you answered that question as well.

Comment: @Geobits I tried to keep my question away from that answer, but I think the effort is not enough, what should I ask to generate then, so that The question has nothing to relate from other question-answers?

Comment: I don't know *what* you should ask, it just seems like any winner here is going to be eerily similar to the answers there.

Comment: @MukulKumar maybe the long code should generate the short code? But don't change this question to that, the change is way too substantial. But it might be an idea for another quine-related challenge (if it hasn't been asked before).

Comment: @Geobits how about concatenating two strings?

Comment: @m.buettner You got me a nice idea for my next question :)

Comment: It's too bad this is /so hard/ in ~-~!, as you can only take multiple inputs to a function via currying but it's insanely hard to put a function inside a function and it'd take thousands of characters to take base 10 input from the console...and it's really bad for compression. Imagine doing this with wires and a battery, then you've got how hard it is to do it in ~-~!.

Comment: Can you specify a range? Otherwise many answers will just make arbitrarily large bases and their score will continue to diverge towards infinity. To see why, consider let's say I handle the range MININT..MAXINT, and I have them set to -128 and 127. I could easily increase my score by setting MININT and MAXINT to -32768 and 32767 (orders of magnitude more output code, only 4 more chars in the source), and then again by moving to 32 bit, 64 bit, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Longest code to add two numbers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22921/longest-code-to-add-two-numbers)

Comment: I don't understand, are the numbers you want to multiply supposed to be parameters for the original program or the generated program?

Comment: @Tal the long program generated by your short program should take input and output answer not the short program.

Comment: "Do NOT use unnecessary statements to increase the score. " Would you give an example as to what would qualify as an unnecessary statement?

Comment: Also, why write to a `.txt` file? It's not plaintext, it's code.

Comment: @user80551 That is simple, you have to write the longest code in only necessary statements like `cout<<"ab/b/b"` would display `ab` then erase them from the output screen making then unnecessary. I ASKED TO WRITE THE LONGEST CODE IN `.TXT` FILE THROUGH THE SHORTEST CODE!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## perl/perl, unlimited score under original rule with unlimited range

Here's some code which doesn't win:

```
$l=-2**5-1;
$h=2**5;
sub p{print@_}
p"sub add {(\$i,\$j)=\@_;\n";
for($i=$l;$i<=$h;++$i){
  for ($j=$l;$j<=$h;++$j){
    p" return ".($i*$j)." if (\$i == $i) && (\$j == $j);\n";
  }
}
p"}print add(<>,<>)\n";
```

The output has this form:

```
sub add {($i,$j)=@_;
 return 1089 if ($i == -33) && ($j == -33);
 return 1056 if ($i == -33) && ($j == -32);
 return 1023 if ($i == -33) && ($j == -31);
 return 990 if ($i == -33) && ($j == -30);
...
 return 928 if ($i == 32) && ($j == 29);
 return 960 if ($i == 32) && ($j == 30);
 return 992 if ($i == 32) && ($j == 31);
 return 1024 if ($i == 32) && ($j == 32);
}print add(<>,<>)
```

the output file is 181030 bytes long, but after stripping spaces and newlines, it is only 133109 bytes long. so, the score is 133109/248 = 536.7289...

Here's some other code that doesn't win - it is the same program except the first 2 lines:

```
$l=-2**6-1;
$h=2**6;
```

the output file is 718138 bytes long, but after stripping spaces and newlines, it is only 532233 bytes long. so, the score is 532233/248 = ~2146. better! using 7 yields a score of ~8750, 8 yields ~35347, 9 yields ~149129, 10 yields 151100000 non-space / 250 = 604,400 ....

of course we can do this as long as we want. the size of the source program, n, will increase as O(log(n)). the size of the output program is O(2**n). The limit of 2**n/log(n) as n goes to infinity is clearly infinity, so if I just substitute in my favorite large number, a googolplex, I win (until someone suggests googolplex+1).

Comment: What is the kind of output ? like you may give first non-repetitive lines.

Comment: First time I could actually read Perl. It generates a function named `add` which takes two parameters. It then populates that function with return statements looking like `return 39 if ($i == 13) && ($j == 3);`, using all values from `$l` to `$h` for `$i` and `$j`. Smartass bending of the "only unnecessary statements" rule.

Comment: Mukul, I edited the answer to include some sample output.

Comment: @skibrianski well that's finite then, because the value the variables i,j can hold are finite. But, quite large.

Comment: Mujul. Finite, but unlimited. Give me any number and I can choose a larger size output (or score) by simply adjusting those variables.

Comment: @skibrianski to get user's attention you should use `@` character before the name. and please show me how would you multiply 99999^(99999) to itself through your generated program.

Comment: @MukulKumar, like any other combination of numbers, you simply go down the list until you get to the case for $i == $BIGNUM && $j == $BIGNUM. According to Wolfram Alpha, 99999^99999 < 2^1660946 ( wolframalpha.com/input/?i=99999%5E99999+%3C+2%5E1660946 ). So, simply replace the first two lines with: $h=2**1660946; $l=-2**1660946-1; and you'll output a program that can deal with 99999^99999.

Answer (score 10):

## C, 27297/245 = 111.4

#### Source code (245 bytes)

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(int c,char**v){char*s;FILE*f=fopen("/tmp/x.c","w");fprintf(f,"#include<stdio.h>\n#include<stdlib.h>\nmain(){int a=%s,b=%s;printf(\"%s * %s = %%d\\n\",a*b);}",v[1],v[2],v[1],v[2]);fclose(f);system("cc -E /tmp/x.c >add.c");}
```

When compiled and run with two integer arguments on the command line, this generates another C file containing the necessary code to calculate their product, and compiles it with the `-E` flag. This flag specifies that the compiler should stop after the preprocessing stage and output the processed source code (which will include the entire contents of `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`).

#### Output file (27297 bytes)

```
# 1 "/tmp/x.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/tmp/x.c"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 1 3 4
# 64 "/usr/include/stdio.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/_types.h" 1 3 4
# 27 "/usr/include/_types.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/sys/_types.h" 1 3 4
# 32 "/usr/include/sys/_types.h" 3 4
# 1 "/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h" 1 3 4
# 33 "/usr/include/sys/_types.h" 2 3 4
```

`********* LINES 13-1273 OMITTED *********`

```
long long
  strtoq(const char *, char **, int);
unsigned long long
  strtouq(const char *, char **, int);

extern char *suboptarg;
void *valloc(size_t);







# 3 "/tmp/x.c" 2
main(){int a=6,b=7;printf("6 * 7 = %d\n",a*b);}
```

#### Result of running the output code

The output file is saved as `add.c`, which can be compiled and run normally:

```
$ ./a.out 6 7
$ cc add.c -o add
$ ./add
6 * 7 = 42
$
```

Answer (score 4):

## perl, 125 chars, score 1,630,326,497.312

Same basic approach as my other answer, but this time bounded between -32768 and 32767 per the updated rules, and all unnecessary whitespace stripped completely:

```
$l=-($h=32767)-1;print"sub a{";for$i($l..$h){print"return ".$i*$_." if\$_[0]==$i&&\$_[1]==$_;"for$l..$h;}print"}print a<>,<>"
```

The output program begins like so:

```
sub a{return 1073741824 if $_[0]==-32768&&$_[1]==-32768;return 1073709056 if $_[0]==-32768&&$_[1]==-32767;
```

and ends:

```
return 1073643522 if $_[0]==32767&&$_[1]==32766;return 1073676289 if $_[0]==32767&&$_[1]==32767;}print a<>,<>
```

The output program is 190GB long. More precisely, 203790812164 bytes. Score = 203790812164 / 125 = 1630326497.312

Answer (score 4):

### Windows Command Script: ~1,000,000,000 pts

Code:    158 bytes

Output: ~158000000000 bytes

```
echo>.txt @goto :%%1_%%2
set,=for /l %%a in (-32768 1 32767) do call :
%,%1 %%a
:1
%,%2 %1 %%a
:2
set/a]=%1*%2
echo :%1_%2>>.txt
echo @echo.%]%^&exit/b0>>.txt
```

The output pretty much consists of:

```
@goto :%1_%2
:-32768_-32768
@echo.1073741824&exit/b0
:-32768_-32767
@echo.1073709056&exit/b0
...
:32767_32767
@echo.1073676289&exit/b0
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 142 bytes

```py
c='def m(a,b):\n'
L=32768
a=-L
while(a<L):
 b=-L
 while(b<L):c+=f' if a=={a}and {b}==b:return {a*b}\n';b+=1
 a+=1
F=open('c.txt','w')
F.write(c)
```

Score unknown for the moment, <s>but I think it's more than a billion.</s> Nope, probably just below a billion.

### Score update

The program has a minimum length of `111669149696` or about 111 billion. This means that the minimum score of this answer is roughly 780 million.

It also has a maximum length of roughly 150 billion, which indicates that **the score is between 730 and 1050 million**. My score is most likely in the middle of that range, i.e. about **890 million**.

Basically writes a function `m` to a file `c.txt` using two while loops.